# Unanswered Question Mitigation

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that the number of unanswered questions on SO is getting to be a very large number (as of this writing 14942 pages of 50).  The last of these unanswered questions was last modified June 28 2013.  That seems like a long time ago and a lot of extra data in the unanswered bin.  I'm under the notion that the unanswered bin should be a place for difficult to answer questions and such, not some giant void where if a question gets past the first few pages it's "lost".

So the question here is what can be done about the large number of unanswered questions?  Ideally they'd all be answered, but that just seems like a pipe dream for now.  How do we reduce the number of questions in the unanswered bin other than answering questions?  Is there a certain way we can flag a question to be closed? Is there some other mechanism to take care of this?  Is there nothing being done about it and a new solution should be created?

I haven't found a good answer on this thus far in my searching, so I was thinking of a new solution to the problem.  If a question went unanswered for a long period of would it hurt for it to have a tag (like 'archive') added to it, which would remove it from the unanswered bin?

Comment: Seems like a non-problem.

Comment: @bjb568, old questions can become irrelevant as time passes; wouldn't it be nice to clean up some of that?  Or am I the only one that this bothers?

Comment: Relax. Nobody needs to go deleting all old things. So what if there are a bunch of question? Does it matter?

Comment: @bjb568, don't get me wrong here, I don't want to delete them.  I just don't want them cluttering up the unanswered bin for more recent, more relevant questions that may have got shoved down the bin due to other questions being more active.

Comment: Why does page 50 concern you when looking at page 1?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily.  But as I gather it, this network is for the sharing of ideas and concepts.  If I have something worth while to contribute to a topic on page 50, and I'm on page 1, I'm probably not going to have the time or fortitude to make it to and share that contribution.  I guess my thought is simply, the less stuff the better.

Comment: The less stuff you have, the less stuff you have. It seems to be a common misconception on SE that you have to answer every question that you see. You don't. Maybe somebody will find one of the questions useful. Maybe it will be upvoted, edited, or commented on to bring it to attention of the community. Maybe it will get an answer. Questions are good, not bad.

Comment: I don't see the benefit of putting the older ones into another bin. If you look at the new ones, you won't see the old ones, so, in that sense, another bin makes no difference. And if sorting by votes, you likely want to see all of them, not just the recent ones.

Comment: I like to find challenging questions, but many unanswered questions actually have pretty good anwers not accepted possibly out of pure carelessnes of the author. Somehow getting rid of those would be good.

Comment: @Harald, I'm not certain but I'm pretty sure if you upvote one of those good answers the question will no longer appear as "unanswered"

Comment: @OGHaza, that seems plausible, I went through the first few pages, and couldn't find an upvoted answer.  Maybe I should refactor the question to how can we encourage people to view the unanswered questions.  Maybe have something that notifies people who have been upvoted on the same tags as an unanswered question?

Comment: "Maybe have something that notifies people who have been upvoted on the same tags as an unanswered question?" - there are hopelessly too many unanswered questions in many of the tags (40k for the [tag:c++] tag, for example) for this to be a good idea - I don't want to get a notification every time there's a new unanswered C++ question or I answer a C++ question, or even a notification every time I answer a question with a tag I haven't before (or however you plan for this to work).

Comment: @Dukeling, I was thinking of an opt-in system, that every certain number of days (or by request) an unanswered item from a tag you've been upvoted a certain number of times on is presented to you.  Or maybe to take it even a step further, allow the user to determine how often they receive a notification of this kind.

Comment: @user3507600 Maybe... but only if I can pick the tag(s) (I have little to no interest in seeing random unanswered Java questions, for example, and I'm at +600 for [tag:java]).

Comment: @Dukeling, I can see that being an issue.  Maybe it would be opt-in per tag you were eligible for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure whether my opinion belongs in an answer, as this is my first time on the meta, but I don't like unanswered questions as well. The main problem for me though, is the number of unanswered question that actually do have an answer is too high. Too often answers are rewarded with a comment like: *"thanks a lot, that really helped me out"*, but the answer has not been accepted or they are provided only in a comment.

The problem with the comment-answers is tackled in [another question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments), but this should not be limited to those comments. Would it not be a good idea to allow moderators to accept obviously helpful answers or to use flags for instance?

Comment: Answer doesn't need to be accepted for the question to go 'answered'. They only need at least 1 answer with positive score. If you know that the answer is correct and helpful, upvote it, so the question is 'answered'.

Comment: We have a quota of votes a day. I use many of mine to vote up correct and useful answers that have gone unnoticed. I do this tag-by-tag (of my favourites) and it then leaves me with a small list of questions that can be answered or flagged as unanswerable. Eventually one is left with a tidy list of Qs per tag.

Comment: [status-declined] http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277918/should-users-with-high-rep-be-able-to-accept-answers-to-questions-with-no-accept and others

Comment: I was rather surprised today to look at the number of Questions on the site (2,543,445) and then click the Unanswered Tab to see "2,379,618 questions with no upvoted or accepted answers". The vast majority of Questions, around 93%, do not have accepted or even upvoted answers? I think something has gone very wrong. If I picked up a dictionary that said "200,000 words!" and then opened it and 180,000 of the words had no definition, I would be unlikely to buy it.

Answer (score -7):

Here are some options:

- We should have scores decrease over time as questions go unanswered. This would encourage people to go back and delete lame questions that they posted and forgot about.
- Possibly have questions with no answers and no up-votes be deleted automatically after a year. We could even give users the option to disable this on a per-question basis.
- Give me better ways to navigate unanswered questions. I need some way to mark tags that I don't want to see (in addition to required tags). This info should not persist; it should just be a way to navigate the tree.
- The system could mix in a few old questions randomly on various pages.
- Perhaps we could invent some smart analytics that could remove old questions that are deemed unreadable or unanswerable. And we should warn users a week before deleting their precious questions.

Comment: Are you looking for [the roomba](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006)?

Comment: 1) A lot of old questions are attached to accounts that are no longer active. The bot shouldn't downvote questions due to age (not a valid reason) and shouldn't remove votes otherwise a vote today is worth more than a vote yesterday. 2) The roomba does this already 3) add to your ignore list and things go away. Use the advanced search options, or SEDE to find old unanswered questions that are interesting. 4) Community♦ already pokes old unanswered questions to bump them in the active list. 5) We have smart analytics. The users that analyze and flag or edit old/off-topic questions. :)