# Why do people answer the question in comments and not with an answer post?

Tags: discussion, support

I'm quite new on Stack Exchange (especially Stack Overflow), and I'm disturbed by this answering way.

Why do some "good" users of Stack Overflow prefer to answer in comments and not with an answer post?

Is it a better way to answer a question?

Comment: Because they are not actually ***answering*** the question.

Comment: If you feel their comment merits an answer, ask them to post it as an answer.

Comment: Related post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments

Comment: I do this if the question is so simple that I'd be embarrassed if I got rep for the answer, but don't have the time to search for a duplicate (such questions usually are duplicates). Or if I don't have the time to write a good answer (e.g., including example code).

Comment: Yes, I'll second the opinion that it's done when the answer is so trivial as to not warrant the time investment to produce and actual answer. I often couple this with a close vote. This is saying *"this question doesn't belong here, it's too trivial or otherwise not suited for SO, but here's the solution to your problem anyway."*

Comment: Whenever the question is so simple it can be answered within a sentence or two.  Otherwise, I'd have to flesh out and find funnay imaeg to add; it's sometimes too time consuming.

Comment: They are afraid that people should vote them down.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I contribute to Stack Overflow because I want to help people. I also take a certain amount of pride in giving "good" answers to questions, that is, not only a snippet of code, but also an explanation of the concepts that led to the problem in the first place.

If I know how to solve the problem, but don't have time to write an answer that I think is an appropriate standard, I will often put that answer in a comment. First, this may be enough to help the OP. Second, it may be enough to help someone else to write a good answer. If they don't, I'll generally come back to it later in the day to write it up as a proper answer.

The other circumstance is when the problem is obviously trivial or a very common duplicate. In which case I'll vote to close, but I'll also try to give a brief solution in a comment, because I'm nice.

Comment: I understand the sentiment, but if an answer really only requires a short blurb, an answer is still appropriate. Let the system work the way it's designed. Sometimes the correct answer comes after a fun game of 20 questions in the comments, but even in this case you can hit the minimum character count by answering with: "As mentioned/discussed in the comments, your issue is BLAH BLAH BLAH and the answer is SO ON AND SO FORTH." Beyond that, I don't understand why users (especially high rep users) feel the need to answer in the comments; it works against the design of SO and SE on the whole.