# Question answered in user question or in comments section

Tags: discussion

I don't know how to really word this but I keep following or coming across questions that are either answered by the user in the question post or by other users in the comments.

Should these questions be closed or somehow marked as answered?

Example:

> [image]

The user asking the question saw someone else's comment and then tried it. Copied his comment and pasted it into his question and wrote solved. What is the best way to handle questions/instances like these?

Comment: There are a lot of other relevant questions. Like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256428/why-do-people-answer-the-question-in-comments-and-not-with-an-answer-post), or [this other one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295912/which-option-shall-i-use-to-close-questions-with-answers-in-comments), and more.

Comment: They should definitely not be answered in the question itself.

Comment: Or [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74101/what-to-do-when-op-answers-his-her-own-question-in-an-edit) from uber-meta.

Comment: I don't want to take any credit for someone else's response. But, I feel like it helps to indicate that another other users has already answered. Maybe this is more for the OP than for me

Comment: If you're worried about that, look at the accepted answer in the top duplicate @yivi linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having "solved" in the question body (or in the title) is not good.
The best way will be to create a new answer post it.

You can edit the question (removing the solution) and then post it as a different answer. You can also (and I think you should) give credit for the original commenter. Hopefully, the OP himself/herself will do that and after also mark the answer as accepted.

If you don't want to do that you can comment this course of action on the question and ask the OP to do that.