# Can I comment on a question with a succinct answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

I'm not complaining here, but I am curious. Recently, in this question "[log(10.0) can compile but log(0.0) cannot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294578/log10-0-can-compile-but-log0-0-cannot)", I commented on the question providing a succinct answer as to why `log(0.0)` didn't compile (I said `-lm` needs to go *after* a.c, not before it).

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24294632/1287251) does mention this, but at the very, very end of the lengthy (but overall great) answer. [The second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24294644/1287251) incorrectly suggests that the `-lm` flag is missing altogether, rather than just misplaced.

I added my comment as a succinct explanation so readers didn't have to read a long accepted answer to see the real solution, and also to slightly correct the second answer. For some reason, though, my comment is gone. I'm assuming a mod deleted it. (*edit: and now the comment is back*)

**Generalizing this to other questions**, if there is a question, and it's been answered with a lengthy (though good) answer, and I know I can sum it up in just a sentence or two, should I (and may I) comment on the question with the very succinct answer?

I find it helps future readers to find a concise answer.

Comment: You also could have edited the answer and but the relevant part more up to the front, I think.

Comment: Mostly-duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: Related, but I wouldn't quite call it a duplicate. My specific question was about adding a comment with an answer to a question that already had an accepted answer.

Comment: Oh, I missed the "already had an answer" part.  Not a duplicate, then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shafik's answer is not even long. If someone doesn't have the patience or attention span to read the whole thing, they clearly don't want to know the answer very badly. A comment seems utterly pointless.

Also, we discourage posting answers in comments. If you wanted to post an answer to the question, you should have posted it as an answer. Of course, that doesn't make sense, because Shafik had already posted a perfectly-adequate answer. It would have been something between redundant and rude to copy details out of his and post an inferior answer of your own.

Being able to summarize content effectively is a useful skill, but there are better places to practice it than Stack Overflow. Not everything needs a "TL;DR"<sup>1</sup>. This isn't Twitter.

Sorry…was that too long of an answer? Here: **No, this is pointless.**

<sub><sup>1</sup> Too long; didn't read</sub>

Comment: +1 for the tl;dr. Now, just to clarify, why is Mystical's comment on the same question acceptable? Shafik covers all of that...

Comment: And now to answer my own question (about Mystical's comment): his/her comment [seems to be acceptable because he/she is merely suggesting it as a probability](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261126/1287251).

Answer (score 3):

Your comment was flagged as obsolete so I deleted it.

This tends to be a rather automatic process I'm afraid. It's very rare that a comment is flagged as obsolete when it isn't.

On further inspection it looks like your comment wasn't really obsolete after all. This is probably the first time I've undeleted such a comment.

However, in general you should **not** post a comment as an answer. The only time you might want to post an answer as a comment is if you're really not sure it's the solution and are more suggesting it as a line of inquiry to the OP, otherwise just post it as an answer.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the explanation! Just to clarify, when you say "you should not post a comment as an answer" you mean "you should not post an answer as a comment"?

Comment: @Cornstalks - Both.