# Is it OK to take someone else's comment and post it as your own answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, attribution

This is a question about ethics (and probably may not have a strict answer).

As a user I prefer (especially when the question is 'foggy'), to add a comment proposing an answer or giving hints towards an answer than posting an answer. If my comment is the answer I will later post it as one.

The issue I encounter, in many cases, is the following :
A 3rd user takes my comment and posts it as an answer, the answer is accepted and he takes all the credit (I do not mean the rep point). So is this kind of behaviour ethical, to replicate someone else's' comment and post it as an answer? Can we avoid this kind of situation (e.g. flagging somehow the answer).

I understand (but I not accept) this kind of behaviour from new users since they may doing it just to build reputation, which is still wrong. But what about user with hundreds of rep point, what do they have to earn?

Comment: This might be a duplicate...

Comment: @Cupcake can you provide the link? I searched but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Here's one that's related: [Answerers who only use comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253045/456814). Still looking though...

Comment: Don't have time to keep looking, I'll just post a quick answer.

Comment: On MSE: [Is posting someone's comment as an answer okay?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157889/is-posting-someones-comment-as-an-answer-okay) (but that's from the answerer's perspective)

Comment: @Cupcake as I get it from `Repost the Comment as an Answer: I don't want the reputation points, and I don't think the practice is worth encouraging.` that guy disagrees with that behaviour. Also in my case I post my own comment as an answer if 'user' says that it solved his problem. But the question is can we tackle this behaviour from 3rd users and how?

Comment: I have had this happen once or twice.  Usually it's where there was come comment interaction with the OP and I eventually (after prying the critical info out of Opie) reply with a comment containing the line or two he needs.  Some 3rd party then comes along and posts that line as an answer.  A little chintzy, but no big deal.  In some cases I actually encourage Opie to post my comment as a self-answer, but he seldom does.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a dupe this way around because Roberts answer on the dupe is shorter and more authoritative.

Comment: is closing as a dupe when it was asked first acceptable?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If a user leave's an answer in a comment instead of an actual answer, then I would consider that to be **fair game**, with regard to someone else posting the comment as an answer, with the caveat that **the copied answer *must* cite and link to the original comment**...give credit where credit is due.

You can think of it this way: leaving answers in comments poses no risk to your reputation, since comments can't be downvoted when you're wrong. So it's easy to just post short answers (which aren't fully fleshed out) as comments, since there's no consequence to writing anything incorrect or poorly in that case. Thus, it also costs little time.

**On the other hand**, if someone takes that comment, fleshes it out into a full-fledged answer by adding more details, etc, then that person should get some credit (reputation) for doing so. *They took the time to write a complete answer*. That's something that has value in it...comments are second-class citizens on Stack Overflow, they're somewhat ephemeral, while answers are intended to withstand the test of time.

Additionally, the person who leaves an answer takes on all the risks associated with that if they get the answer wrong, i.e. downvotes. There has to be the possible benefit of upvotes to counter the associated risk.

Personally, however, I would make the answer **community-wiki** in the case of just a verbatim copy of a comment answer, without additional details.

### Option: post your own full answer anyways

That being said, if someone takes a comment you left and posts it as an answer, if you come back within a reasonable time (like maybe a few days at most, though sooner is better) and post your own **fully-fleshed out answer that expands on the comment that you left**, then oftentimes the person who asked the question will decide to unaccept the other answer and accept yours instead...which is totally fine, in my opinion, since you *were* the person who came up with an answer in the first place.

**Don't do this**, however, if you're just going to take your comment and paste it verbatim into an answer, without adding additional details. Because then if someone else had already posted your comment as an answer (without adding additional details), then this is kind of an under-handed move, in my own opinion. You chose to post an answer as a comment, instead of a full-fledged answer, so you basically **forfeited** your opportunity to earn reputation for it.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion there's more...I forgot to add this in my first revision.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit hey, Mr. *English Police*, didn't you know that ["anyways" is an American bastardization of "anyway"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/anyways). It's *in the dictionaries* now! `:P` A smart English teacher once told me that "language changes over time and distance". I'll say "anyways" wheneva I want! Power to the People! Resist Authority!

Comment: @Cupcake Yeah you basically just validated my edit ;p Yuckkkk

Comment: Let's just change it from "anyways" to "irregardless" and split the difference.

Answer (score 4):

First and foremost consider that what you're posting is mostly not *your intellectual property*. It's not like we're inventing new stuff on SO here, for the most part. Most of *programming* is not inventing new stuff, we're just combining pieces of logic in different ways.

As such, an answer is not your intellectual property which only you may distribute. On the contrary, we are hoping to spread knowledge to everyone and we hope that those people will spread it further. If you feel mistreated when the knowledge you posted is repeated by someone else, you have the wrong goals.

Having said that, if you have invested a lot of time into going back and forth about the issue with the OP in the comments and have finally arrived at a solution, you may feel a little bit cheated if someone just takes your time investment and runs with it. Or if someone just copy and paste's your comment verbatim as an answer without even the slightest hint at your contribution. That's not *nice*. However, there's no rule against it. Especially if the poster should add their own commentary and write it in their own words, there's nothing wrong with that. Knowledge is free (as in beer *and* speech), it's not *yours* to keep. An officially posted answer "completes" a question and serves future visitors to more easily discover the knowledge; that's the goal.

If you want your official 15 seconds of internet fame and fortune, post an answer yourself.

Comment: I will agree only with the paragraph 'Having said that.....that's the goal'. I consider 'combining pieces' as a skill, that many may not have, so my post is my 'intellectual property' even if it is not licensed as one. Community is all about giving and taking, so if you 'take' you have at least 'give' the credits.

Comment: Personally, I could hardly care less. Often I'll try to hint the OP in the right direction in the comments if it's a mostly trivial problem. I want people to discover knowledge themselves. If someone discovers it, with or without my help, and posts it as a good answer, more power to them. I'd only get annoyed at wholesale no-effort copy-n-paste jobs. But even just taking a comment and reformulating it as an answer means someone has taken my hint and thought about it and apparently learned enough from it that they were able to create an answer. That's perfectly fine with me.