# Question was solved by a comment: how do I remove it from unanswered list?

Tags: support, comments, unanswered-questions

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25501518/error-while-unpacking-the-zip-from-zip), where I received 0 votes and 0 answers.

However, I *did* get the correct answer as a comment.

Since my problem has been solved, I want to indicate that the question is answered and remove it from the "unanswered questions" section. How can I do this?

Comment: see also [Cupcake's excellent answer to a related question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265676/366904)

Answer (score 3):

Ask the person who answered to post the answer as an "answer" not as a comment. The system doesn't allow you to mark a comment as the answer—comments aren't intended as a way to answer.

If the user doesn't post the answer, you can post it yourself, after 24 hours. If he does post the answer, be sure to mark it correct so others know as well.

Comment: It isn't an intelligence problem. Comments and answers are intentionally kept separate. They serve different purposes.

Comment: I know, it wasn't the easiest way of phrasing the statement. Guess I'll rephrase it to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

If someone provides the answer in a comment then you should post a comment asking them to convert it into an answer.

If they do post an answer you can then accept that answer.

If they don't post an answer after a few days then post the answer yourself (referencing the comment and possibly making the answer community wiki) which you can then accept.

It's the accepting of an answer that marks the question as "solved".

Comment: We're either great minds or fools.

Comment: Find it kinda funny that three of us answered the same thing, at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Either leave a comment asking the commenter to write up a formal answer to the question and then accept it. If they don't wish to do so/don't do so after a day or two, write up the answer yourself - attributing it to the user(s) who made the comments) - then mark it as a Community Wiki and accept it as the answer.

Either way you need to accept an answer in order for your question to not show as unanswered.