# Is it okay to comment plausible solutions?

Tags: discussion, questions, comments

Sometimes I can think of a solution off the bat, but I don't have time and/or resources to confirm this and develop a full and detailed answer.

Is it okay to comment these plausible solutions to try to lead the OP or other responders to discovering the cause of the issue and developing a good answer?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4217/250916

Comment: I think it's okay. Can't think of anything that would make such comments unhelpful.

Comment: @Trilarion I saw what you did there.

Comment: It is, but it also leads to the unfortunate situation where you 'break' the question. You do an educated guess, this happens to be the solution, you get a thanks! and the original poster flees, never to be seen again. You can still post an answer, but don't expect to ever see it getting accepted. As someone who is still working hard to get the necessary reputation to make a difference on SO, that sucks.

Comment: I hope so because I do it all the bloody time.  If what @gimby says happens (and it does), I formulate an answer and spend the time to fill it in with relevant references or code.

Comment: @Gimby, wouldn't the better solution be to teach the OPs not to hit and run (don't do the bad thing), as opposed to teaching commenters not to share information (do do the good thing)?

Comment: @cp.engr, How do you "teach" someone to not hit-and-run when they have already run (and never come back)?

Comment: @Makyen, I guess the best we can do is to comment saying as much, and generally try to encourage good community behavior. It may not work sometimes. Regardless, as a user, I'd rather have some/partial/cryptic info than no info at all.

Comment: can we add a suggestion flag, so readers know it is not an answer, but a suggestion that isn't tested?

Comment: @cp.engr you're trying to read things that are not there. I'm merely warning what might happen.

Comment: If you're being helpful, be helpful. I'd rather have a couple comments pointing me in the right direction than nothing at all.

Comment: Note that while this practice is common and accepted here, on certain other Stack Exchange sites moderators will ruthlessly delete any comment that resembles an answer.

Comment: @Trilarion: See my answer to discover how such comments are _grossly harmful_ overall.

Comment: @travelingbones has a nice idea that could work as a compromise

Comment: @ssube: You have no way of knowing whether the comments are _actually_ helpful, or giving you wrong information, because comments are not part of the peer review system. That is potentially a _lot_ worse than being told nothing at all. I saw it happen just last week; OP never came back after receiving what they interpreted to be a "helpful" comment but was in reality complete nonsense... and couldn't be downvoted by anybody.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Sure, totally. I do it all the time.

Just note that the unwritten law is that if you provide an answer in a comment, it’s fair game for someone else to take it and flesh it out into an answer - ideally, acknowledging you, of course.

Comment: Yes - I do this as well. Sometimes, it's an educated guess (which then may be proven correct by someone else), and sometimes I quickly comment, think it over and [write up a full answer later](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39298916/2564301). Unless it already got an answer, of course.

Comment: I think a plausible solution is better than waiting for the precise answer. That way the OP will get a chance to learn and maybe find the answer himself.

Comment: @TigerShark Have you tried to turn it off and on again?

Comment: @Trilarion I might be an idiot, but what do you mean by that? Was my comment really that wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing here, but I think Trilarion was jokingly giving you an example of the most common plausible solution.

Comment: @SamyBencherif, there is a discussion [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265675/is-it-ok-to-take-someone-elses-comment-and-post-it-as-your-own-answer) (and in its duplicate), if you want to read further regarding "taking someone's comment and posting it as an answer"

Comment: @TigerShark Sorry, no, you're definitely no idiot. I was just making fun by citing the most famous plausible solution to almost everything. Actually I think now it doesn't really makes that much sense here. Sorry.

Comment: Shame! Shame! Shame!

Answer (score 2):

I do this kind of thing all the time. The only doubt is where to draw the boundary between a comment and an answer. An answer doesn't have to be working and tested code (and generally I prefer not to provide working and tested code because I believe the poster will learn more if they have to apply some effort to understand the proposed solution). If all that I'm doing is telling the OP why their code doesn't work, then I'll either make this a comment or an answer depending on how they phrased the question. But if the key to solving the problem is knowing that a prepareMagicWidget() function exists, then I'll probably make that an answer.

Answer (score -3):

## No!

The comments section is for critiquing and for requesting clarification. Period.

I've touched on this before[,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247446/155739) but, in short:

- **I don't have time to write a full answer now**
  Okay, write it later!
- **I will never have time to write a full answer**
  Okay, well, don't then. Let someone else do it.
- **I'm not sure enough about my suggestion to write it as an answer**
  Then posting it at all could be damaging to the OP. Watch other answers, learn a bit, then post an answer later if you feel you're surer about your idea.
- **I just want to give the OP a hint**
  Invite him/her/it to a chatroom.
- **I don't want the rep from an answer**
  Give it away in bounties to answers elsewhere that you feel are outstanding, or make your answer *community wiki*.
- **The question is off-topic so I don't want to post an answer and get berated**
  If the question is off-topic then it is off-topic. It should not be answered at all. Writing an answer in comments both enables the naughty OP *and* creates a spasmic mess of anti-Q&A, surely the antithesis of Stack Exchange.

When you write a [possible] [mini] answer in the comments section, you *completely* bypass the entire peer review system that is Stack Overflow's purpose for being. If your comment is wrong, it cannot be downvoted. It does not enter into *any* review queues. It cannot be edited. Your intentions are good, and you think you are "helping", but your action is actually harmful on aggregate.

Some others here are saying "yes, it's fine, because I do it all the time". Sorry, but that is not a reason.

The answer section is for answers. Nothing else is for answers.

[Here](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2299/14359) is basically the same explanation from a different SE site's meta. I can't see anything there that isn't applicable to Stack Overflow and, frankly, it continues to baffle me that the majority seem to accept this approach here.

Comment: "*I don't want the rep from an answer*" you can post as a community answer, too.

Comment: Good point @null; that's another way to go. Thanks!

Comment: I predict that you'll be downvoted into oblivion, but I agree with this answer. I'll go down with you!

Comment: @KevinWorkman: That means a lot :)

Comment: This seems about as wrong as an answer to this question could be. *So many* useful answer started as a suggestion in comments. If possible solutions were never posted in comments, we would lose out on an unbelievable amount of useful information. All of those proposed solutions are vastly inferior to just posting the comment. You're burying things in red tape.

Comment: @DCShannon: This has nothing to do with "red tape" and I don't believe I ever suggested that it did. The SE model was constructed, quite carefully, for a dang good reason. You lot are now just stomping all over it like every design decision was completely arbitrary. Silly. Experts Exchange here we come...

Comment: I'm calling it red tape because all your reasons for not doing this are bureaucratic in nature, and you're ignoring all the practical benefits. Discarding practical, observed benefits of a process that is in place and working well for imagined procedural benefits of an idealized process is pretty much the definition of red tape. There's not a problem to be fixed.

Comment: @DCShannon: Sorry, no, they're not bureaucratic in the slightest. You're ignoring all the practical downsides, which I have clearly enumerated in simple language. I'm not just chasing some utopian dream. The problem to be fixed was a problem with other websites, which was fixed by the creation of Stack Overflow _with its deliberately-constructed model_, which you and your friends are doing your best to bypass for some reason! Meanwhile, I see no practical benefits of your approach; for those that are being imagined, I provided alternatives ... also clearly listed and in simple language.

Comment: I feel that I've understood what you've said perfectly, and strongly disagree. That is all.

Comment: @DCShannon: It's certainly your right to disagree. Just thought it might be nice if someone actually presented some counter-arguments instead of making things up about the arguments I've made. That kind of makes me think you _didn't_ understand my answer, because you haven't actually addressed anything it said yet. Oh well! Have a nice evening :)

Comment: What if someone has a partial answer or suggestion they can't explain or they're not sure about at all, on a question not asked too recently that hasn't received any answers yet? Are you suggesting that they not post it at all or that they post it as a (low quality) answer? Maybe there's no place for it if we're following the rules to the letter, but such a suggestion or partial answer can be very helpful to OP as well as anyone else visiting the question, and to someone potentially able to turn it into a more complete or concrete answer (in a way that posting it in chat won't).

Comment: I am gobsmacked by the lack of support for this answer.  If consensus is to be obeyed on StackOverflow, then why does the comment box's placeholder text says: _Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments._?

Comment: @mickmackusa: I'm heartened, at least, to see that this policy is being increasingly strictly enforced on other SE sites.

Answer (score -4):

I think it would be better to post it as an answer and edit it later if need be. Sometimes even detailed answers get comments that ask for clarification on certain things, so why not start at a lower detail level to begin with? The level of detail necessary to answer the question depends on the asker anyway and is not necessarily easy to predict.

Remember that partial answers are also allowed. Having an idea for a solution is one of the first steps to get to a solution. It might be the one the asker is missing.

If you post it as an answer, you might want to point out that it's just a partial one, which might help keeping downvotes away.

Comment: If you haven't confirmed your answer works, it's more of a hunch than an answer IMO.

Comment: @ssube you can delete answers.

Answer (score -8):

We are a community of developers. I think posting plausible solutions is okay as long as we express that they are simply *plausible*, not necessarily 100% the correct answer.. This way we can create an open forum of opinons and ideas rather than a thread of arguments

Comment: Are you saying it's OK to post such comments, or that it's OK to post such answers? We are NOT an "open forum of opinions and ideas".

Comment: The question is not about "**posting** plausible solutions" as answers. It's about making **comments** giving plausible solutions. Such a comment, by nature, does not need a self-disclaimer that it is not an answer--we already know that it is not an answer, because it is a comment.

Comment: Typically we don't have to worry about opinions and arguments, because we keep everything here objective. Questions which ask for our opinion are closed as opinion-based, and arguments which point out wrong answers are pretty straight forward, and merit downvotes if not addressed.

Comment: Stack Exchange was deliberately and explicitly created not to be an open forum of opinions and ideas. There are other places for that (and they devolve rather rapidly into nonsense that cannot be verified). Feel free to have a little look at the history of the network and why the model was designed the way it was designed. People are now literally using the wrong tool for the job and claiming it's fine, without asking themselves _why_ things were made the way they were. Even more baffling given that many of those people were there at the beginning!