# What is "Good Stack Overflow Citizenship"?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, ethics

I've been a SO users for a few years, but I've only had the courage to start giving back about a year ago. Along the way, I've learned a lot about how to behave from watching other users, taking the tour, reading FAQ, getting suspended, and making my own decisions about what is good/bad for the community as a whole.

Every once in a while I feel myself getting aggravated when I see users behaving in a way that *seems* like gaming the system (de-prioritizing what is good for the site, for personal gain) or generally creating low-quality content on the site.

I recently had a very brief chat with @deceze about what he considered "good citizenship".  I wanted to ask a highly active `php` user with lots of SO experience, reputation, badges, and the moderator status was the cherry on top. If I couldn't trust his opinion, who could I trust, right?

Unfortunately, he didn't have a ready-made online document for me to digest and espouse, but he said he did have scattered posts across Meta that represented his beliefs.  As I offered a few itemized scenarios that I thought were poor citizenship, he returned with his view (which was different from my view but certainly justified) and I have recalibrated my beliefs as a result.

One link that he offered in our discussion pointed to his post @ [Advantage to Old Users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254967/2943403). This talks about "magic unicorn points" relating to "trust", but then I said that I see high rep users that conduct themselves poorly.  Badges *may* give a truer sense of citizenship, but again I don't think that these metrics can be fully relied upon either.

Although deriving my own set of beliefs after reading Meta pages is a great way to be a good, free-thinking SO citizen, it would be much more efficient if I could just trust some of the existing pillars in this community to lay down some firm points regarding what they think about quality citizenship.  I don't want to know about FAQ/help pages, I've read them.  I would like to hear about advice that transcends what can be done, and focus specifically on actions that *should be* done that have a positive site-wide cultural impact.

I'm also interested in identifying role models to emulate.  When I asked deceze for suggested role models, he dropped this link on me:  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/topusers. While there are users on that list with undoubtedly high levels of expertise, their rep points are not necessarily an indicator of the quality of their citizenship. So that I don't carry on being too vague, I see some of the users doing things like (I won't write a long list):

1. Answering basic, no effort, mega-duplicates when you have tens or hundreds of thousands of rep and a gold badge in one or more of the question's tags (you know full-well that it is a hammerable duplicate).
2. Commenting solutions.
3. Generally making other users feel unwelcome with unconstructive interactions.

For the record, I have recently read these pages that directly or indirectly discuss matters related to SO citizenship:

- [What to do when a high-rep user is willfully breaking site rules/meta consensus?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/301016/what-to-do-when-a-high-rep-user-is-willfully-breaking-site-rules-meta-consensus)
- [High reputation users answering totally off-topic question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313880/high-reputation-users-answering-totally-off-topic-question)
- [Replace accept rate with citizenship level](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165179/replace-accept-rate-with-citizenship-level)
- [Make SO a better place for good!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253072/make-so-a-better-place-for-good)
- [Handling “Problematic” Stack Overflow participants](http://Handling%20%E2%80%9CProblematic%E2%80%9D%20Stack%20Overflow%20participants)
- [Feature needed to incentivize more positive activity mostly orthogonal to current incentives](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214072/feature-needed-to-incentivize-more-positive-activity-mostly-orthogonal-to-curren)
- [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users)
- [What's the best way to boost my Stack Overflow score?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50148/whats-the-best-way-to-boost-my-stack-overflow-score)

This is a deliberately broad question, because I don't want to accidentally exclude any good advice that you might have. It is also completely opinion-based, but this is okay for a discussion question right? Here's hoping this isn't inst-closed because this took me a long time to compose. Anyhow...

1. Please offer *your personal* stance on prominent, frequent behaviors that represent good and/or bad citizenship, how *you personally* promote/combat these behaviors, why *you* think these are important to identify, and how successful *you* are with your attempts to promote/combat.
2. If you consider yourself to be a good SO citizen, what does your typical "session" look like? Do you start in the Review queues? Straight to Q&A?  Do you set personal goals to achieve before you go to Q&A, like: so many reviews, so many flags, revisit your old answers, etc.?

Responses don't need to be a 30-point list, I'll take a 3-point mantra if you feel strongly about your beliefs.

If anyone wants to get extreme, you could produce an online video featuring a rainbow unicorn/pony that speaks very tongue-in-cheek about good SO citizenship. Then when I see a user that is being a "poor citizen", then I can just send them to your video.

In the end, this is about refining my behavior and serving the site that has dramatically improved my coding knowledge.

Comment: I totally don't understand this closure justification.  This is directly about Stackoverflow.  Someone please suggest what I should reword to make this question qualify. [disappointed face]

Comment: FWIW, I voted to close it as opinion based, though I could have gone with too broad instead. I think the close reason is wrong but I still think it should be closed.

Comment: Agreed, this is both broad and opinion based.  But aren't discussion questions going to be opinion based?  Isn't Meta opinion based?

Comment: There are limits on that though and personally I think this crosses the line. Others may differ of course, we're not all clones here.

Comment: @RobertLongson, you mean that [we are all individuals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QereR0CViMY), don't you?

Comment: Fair enough.  I just don't see the difference between what I've asked and what other pages (like the related pages that I referenced in my question) have asked.  Very opinion based.

Comment: I've removed the request to include suggestions for role models. Now the question has just two question parts that can easily be merged into a single answer. This question asks: what are prominent, frequent behaviors that are good or bad and how do you promote/combat them?

Comment: @mickmackusa even that will just cause fights. What if good/bad depends upon whom you ask, and how you ask.

Comment: @MartinJames I want to hear both sides so that I can decide which side of the fence I want to be on. I am sure there are things I haven't considered/encountered.  I would like to hear the differing, consolidated mantras of pillars in this community.  No fights need to break out if people speak their mind and offer their logical justifications.  Let's not go into this with fear.

Comment: 'Do you think that it's a good thing that new users are so often heavily downvoted, often without any explanation, and never return?  Such downvoting is unnecessary, unhelpful and disheartening, and often seen a malicious. We were all newbies once and SO should show more consideration.  Should such newbie downvoting activity be discouraged and/or sanctioned?' [yes]

Comment: 'Do you think that it's a good thing that new users post so may duplicate questions without any sign of diligent research?  Is it useful that the limited resource of skilled and experienced developers continually waste time on the same old questions over, and over again?  Do you think that failure to diligently research problems before posting to SO should be discouraged and/or sanctioned by downvoting?' [yes]

Comment: @MartinJames: Is that supposed to be an question towards the OP?

Comment: If anyone would not like to post an answer because they predict that their post will be challenged (and you don't like the idea of your opinion being challenged) perhaps Meta isn't a good place for you to post.  I believe some boldness will be required in the answers to my question.

Comment: Close-voting as "Too broad": _"what are prominent, frequent behaviors that are good or bad and how do you promote/combat them?"_ is too unspecific to discuss. Generally, a question on Meta should focus on __one__ specific behavior, with answers discussing different options to discusrage / encourage said behavior.

Comment: @Cerbrus nah - it's an example of how such discussions are likely to go:(

Comment: The "mantras" that I am targeting are often found in users' profiles.  I would like to see what veterans do as a matter of habit for the good of this site.

Comment: @mickmackusa 'boldness' on SO often results in suspensions, and the impact of a suspension depends largely on who get suspended.  'One-account-per-question' newbies with 1 rep don't care.  Skilled and esperienced users with high rep do care.

Comment: @mickmackusa ' I would like to see what veterans do as a matter of habit for the good of this site' now, that sounds like research work.   You doing a dissertation on SO?

Comment: This isn't any more of a Rorschach blot than "Why is SO so negative of late?", may as well give it a shot.

Comment: Question 1 is like 4 questions.  It's one thing to talk about what we think constitutes "good citizenship" (and why), but it's an entirely another thing to cite examples and self-evaluate.  That portion IMO make your question too broad.  Your question feels more like an essay prompt than a directly answerable question.

Comment: Yup, in the end it could have been written much more succinctly: _What is “Good Stack Overflow Citizenship”? Discuss._ :P

Comment: @yivi Then I have a counter question: *What is "Stack Overflow Citizenship"?* Last time I checked this was only a Q&A site.

Comment: Related: *[Good Stack Overflow Citizen by Jeff Atwood](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRRWDf-xB2Y)* (YouTube)

Comment: Related: *[Is there a community on Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow sites like there is on Quora?](https://www.quora.com/Quora-vs-Stack-Exchange/Is-there-a-community-on-Stack-Exchange-Stack-Overflow-sites-like-there-is-on-Quora)* (Quora)

Comment: ***use your votes.***

Comment: Look, the core of what I am trying to do here is collect the diverse philosophies of the most engaged, caring users.  You can think of this page as a place to park fragments of a "How to be a good SO citizen" book.  Invariably, some of the most talented and dedicated users will burn-out or otherwise drift away from participating on SO; when this happens "the torch/baton" gets dropped.

Comment: ...Newer users may try to fill the void, but few things are as good as the original.  People speak of the cultural decay on SO; I think this can be largely addressed by providing upcoming/future pillars with tried&tested roadmaps (or commandments, if you like) so that they can hit the ground running.

Comment: to clarify... We need more people using the tools available to them. If someone is being rude/offensive, use the tool that deals with it. If someone asks a low quality question, use the tool that deals with it. If someone provides a high quality question/answer, use the tool that deals with it. Too many people just focus on one of those rather than all of them.

Comment: @Gimby: Can't tell if your comment is satire...

Comment: FWIW, I think this question is fine and should stay open. Please stop repeatedly opening and closing it. I've put a temporary hold on that.

Comment: Stack Overflow **is what it is** (it has developed over time but is a **privately held** website), because **people** are what they are, if you have personal major problems with it, **don't use it**. If you think is a bad influence on wider society tell your local government. Things are not as complicated as some like make out. There are things you can do.

Comment: Stack Overflow can be an intimidating place for new members. I realize that **many** Q's from users <10 rep are duplicated or missing information, but there are so many Help & FAQ pages that one can't be expected to find them all on their own on Day 1. **Try to *Welcome* new members** and point them to some key pages (like "[ask]" & "[mcve]" & the [tour] & [Jon's "Perfect Question" tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/) instead of an ***unexplained* down-vote**. There is a **[Be Nice Policy](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)** which I have never seen enforced.

Comment: *(...hmm, I guess, the* **[mcve]** *magic link doesn't work here, even though* \[ask] *and* \[help/on-topic] *do.)*

Comment: @ashleedawg The problem is that voting and *be nice* are orthogonal. Yes, it would be nicer if every downvote was explained, but that’s simply unrealistic at this scale. That’s why there are canned close reasons the user gets to see when the question is eventually closed. *Be nice* doesn’t mean to take everyone by the hand personally. It mostly means *don’t be rude, at least be neutral.*

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Fundamentally the creators of SO dictate what is good citizenship. They design the tools available, the rewards, the punishments and the restrictions. Good citizenship is to use those tools as designed. You don't have as much freedom in this as you may think; *we're all just sheeple!*

Stack Overflow/Exchange became as successful as it is precisely because it enforced specific restrictions over the alternatives. `<hipster voice>` Aaaacshually, I've been following this experiment since before it existed, back when [Atwood](https://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/) and [Spolsky](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/04/16/stackoverflowcom/) were merely ruminating on it in a series of blog posts and [podcast discussions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/04/17/podcast-1/) for some [six to eight weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/476). The status quo at the time was supremely unhelpful forum threads, typically leading to:

[image: Who were you DenverCoder9? What did you see?!]

This is the problem Atwood and Spolsky set out to fix, and they famously came up with:

[image: part wiki, digg/reddit, blog, forum]

They structured around that idea various tools that would encourage and enforce the desired behaviour within this framework. Correct knowledge is rewarded, nonsense is demoted, the best rises to the top, [there should be one and preferably only one obvious](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) answer to every question, no chitchat etc. And because this model worked so well to provide *solutions to problems*, it became popular to the point where so many people jumped on board that most of them have no idea about these core tenets.

But this is still what this site is supposed to accomplish:

- upvote useful, comprehensible, correct content (so more people can find it)
- downvote unhelpful, incomprehensible, incorrect content (so people don't have to wade through it to find the good stuff)
- don't expect you can chitchat here (because nobody wants to read through that to solve their problem)
- don't expect to have deep social interaction here (because this isn't a social network, it's a knowledge base to find answers to problems)

These factors don't really matter:

- the user is a newbie
- the user has a lot of points
- the user has really really tried pinky swear
- any other excuse

None of the above are any reason to allow anyone to post anything that would otherwise be downvote/delete/ban-worthy. If that leads to some social awkwardness and hurt feelings: sorry, this is not a social network. Again, you are here *because* this is not a social network.

As for the grey-zone in-between things like commenting solutions or *not* closing as duplicate… we're all humans. Sometimes we're tired and can't be bothered to find the correct duplicate and also can't be bothered to type a full answer, but nonetheless we can provide a nudge in the right direction. I see that kind of thing actually as real kindness; it helps more than it hurts. One can do both: stick to the rules, but provide something outside those rules too.

Personally speaking, I'm here because I want to maintain this thing as one of the great libraries of knowledge of (programming) humanity. This is the guiding principle, everything else is just fallout from that. Living by the letter of the law only leads to people finding the loopholes; living by the *spirit of the law* is what is sustainable and leads to betterment. So, understand the spirit (briefly outlined above) and act accordingly as best as you can.

There is no prescription on what to do exactly, everyone is concentrating on different parts. You may enjoy fixing spelling and formatting, or you may enjoy the triage queues, or you may just enjoy answering, or just finding duplicates, or just downvoting, or just commenting, or just meta, or any combination thereof. As long as each of those things stays within the desired rules and works towards the betterment of the site, that's good citizenship.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly. It's the simple and noble goal of this community of answers and curators. We are programmers, we saw a problem that needed solving and we did what needed to be done. And yet, there's a necessary larger mission if we are to keep this resource useful for future generations of programmers. Good citizenship demands treating people a little better than they deserve in hopes that they will come to be productive partners in this endeavour. We need the programmers who grow up in the Stack Overflow era to not take it for granted or avoid becoming a part of it.

Comment: @Jon Correct me if I'm wrong, but I interpret that to refer to my "hurt feelings" statement and that I'm possibly not allowing for enough humanity in this? If that's the case, it is implicit to me that of course you first and foremost act like a compassionate mensch. You simply don't elevate that above the functioning of the system, you don't let the social aspect ruin the constraints that make the system work. And in fact, reminding people of the origins of SO, like I do here, is what I see as part of the "larger mission".

Comment: Yeah. I think there's a sense that the only way we get good content is to focus on the goal at all costs. Certainly, we don't ever want to forget the goal, but we don't want to get tunnel vision either. (I know _you know_ this, but I want to make sure future readers know you know too. ;-)

Comment: @JonEricson I know you know that I know that you know that readers know. 

Answer (score 13):

The exhaustive list of what makes a good Stack Overflow citizen and how to do that on a daily basis is probably best left to a book, or a well crafted medium.com post. This isn't that.

Although, we did use to have something similar to this on the "don't do" side. It was deleted. If you are interested in all of that, start with [Why “What Stack Overflow is Not” was deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137795/178816).

Mostly what you are asking is opinion-based... What is good behavior, what is bad behavior? Overall there is a lot of interpretation involved with that analysis, and as a result of a lot of contention with regards to many of the related issues.

With regards to your specific set of 3 observed behaviors: answering mega-dupes, solutions in comments, and non-constructive interactions - these are all rather agreed upon as undesirable. Don't do that.

With regards to frequent suggested behaviors, I would only offer the general set of community observed consensus.

- **Create content which is well researched and will stand the test of time.**
- Close duplicates (when they fit) as soon as possible.
- Close questions (where warranted) as soon as possible.
- Downvote content which is not useful, upvote content which is useful.
- Remove egregious content (such as spam, clearly off topic posts, non answers, etc.)
- Use comments for clarification purposes, and not for solutions or extended debate (meta is an exception).
- In situations where an edit can be made to improve a post without changing its meaning, then make it.
- [Be nice.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)
- <strike>Have fun</strike> (but not too much fun, just like that gray area between fun and hating fun).

In an ideal world, everyone just does the first point, and most of the other stuff isn't really needed. We aren't quite there yet.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164350/discussion-on-answer-by-travis-j-what-is-good-stack-overflow-citizenship).

Comment: In an ideal community, new users might not do the first point, but experienced users doing the 2nd and 3rd (and maybe 4th) points should counter-act that. Striving towards an ideal community is easier than striving towards an ideal world. Although I still think the new user interface can (potentially) make a massive difference to overall question quality.

Comment: *"Use comments for clarification purposes, and not for solutions or extended debate (meta is an exception)."* If I have a partial solution or a suggestion that could be a solution, doesn't that belong as a comment? I guess I'm using a comment here, asking for clarification. :-) (The question is sincere though.)

Comment: @dfd [Is it okay to comment plausible solutions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335190)

Answer (score 4):

The answer is blowing in the wind...

There is no way to answer this question because it's undefined. Except for the very basic rules (e.g. no racism, religious harassment, sexual harassment, etc.).

What good citizenship is depends on the time of asking and the person(s) asked. Good citizenship changes over time as it is impacted by the behavior of the citizens. It's an evolution that we all (can) contribute to.

**So don't look for a role model**

Instead, consider how you want this site to evolve. Behave accordingly and try to impact the evolution in the direction you like. That can be done in several ways like upvote, downvote, close vote, reopen vote or whatever suites your direction.

Likely, you'll experience other users with different views than yours. That doesn't make them bad citizens - nor you a bad citizens. That just how a community works - we can't all agree about everything - but we can still make it a valuable community despite our disagreements.

Comment: Yes, I understand about overt breeches of rules that are outlined in help/FAQs; it would be senseless to echo those points here.  I agree that the definition of good citizenship will evolve -- that is an indicator of a healthy system.  I am interested in the present [zeitgeist](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/zeitgeist) because it will be the product of the cumulative efforts of many faithful volunteers over time.  I don't mind seeing conflicting answers here.  If both parties have logical justifications, then neither is "wrong", and I can decide which way I want to shape my own citizenship.

Comment: This will of course be subjective, but one can certainly mention some things one thinks people should be doing more of, or less of, (or that people are doing the right amount of) that will help (or helps) push [so] in the right direction (which is how I interpret this question).