# Is it valid for a gold tag badge holder to annul other users' votes?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, dupehammer, vote-to-reopen

This is very similar to the question [Is it valid for a diamond moderator to use their powers to override the closing votes of other users, in order to reopen a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404750) My answer to that is yes, and the other answers, as well as the comments on the question and answers suggest that there is a consensus that this is ok.

However, while moderators are trusted to override other users' actions when they see fit, it's not clear to me whether this applies to gold tag badge holders. Just as an example of what I mean, this [timeline](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/406746/timeline) shows

[image]

Since the question was already closed as a duplicate, I can't see any reason for these actions other than to annul the existing reopen votes (unless the user changed their mind in the 5 seconds between closing and reopening). Anyway, it's just an example, and this question is not about what the user intended, but whether it's ok to do this in general.

So my question is

1. If I see a question that I think has been closed correctly, but has some reopen votes, can I use my hammer to annul those votes by reopening it myself, assuming that I think the question can then be correctly close-hammered as a duplicate?
2. Similarly, can I use my hammer to annul a bunch of close votes that I think are incorrect (by close-hammering with a bogus target) and then instantly reopening it? Normally I would just wait for the question to be closed before voting to reopen, but if this close->reopen technique is allowed, this would be quite useful, since I would not be able to single-handedly reopen a question unless it was closed as a duplicate in the first place.

Comment: I don't see how doing so would be any different than waiting another day or two and closing it. If anything, it prevents the 5th user from wasting their vote... effectively increasing the odds it'd get reopened.

Comment: @KevinB Well, it's different in that I'd be casting a vote that I *know* is not the right vote to cast, which may, or may not, be an acceptable thing to do. Also, as I mentioned in the question, if I hammer it closed, I can then reopen single-handedly which is not necessarily something I can do if I wait for others to close.

Comment: in other words, the votes aren't annulled. No one is being deprived of their privilege to cast a reopen vote. The only semi-shady issue here is casting a vote that you don't believe is correct for the purpose of closing the question now rather later. In the end, the result is the same.

Comment: @KevinB Ok, it sounds like you have an answer to my question. Feel free to write an answer if you want. Since you're not asking for clarification on what the question is asking, I'm not going to bother discussing this further in the comments section.

Comment: Mods can do the same thing (in fact I've seen moderators do it quite a lot). If a gold badger thinks that a question should not be closed, then closing and reopening it is perfectly fine IMO.

Comment: The difference with mods doing is mods can do it over and over, where as a gold badge holder only gets one chance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the dupehammer (Mjölnir) still being evaluated, and if so, what is the current outcome?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298807/is-the-dupehammer-mj%c3%b6lnir-still-being-evaluated-and-if-so-what-is-the-curren)

Comment: @gnat No, not even remotely. Where in that question or its answer do you see any mention of a hammer being used to reopen and then close a post, or vice-versa, as I describe in this question?

Answer (score 10):

I'll explain my reasoning:

As you can see, that question already had 4 reopen votes. There was also a discussion in the comments about changing the dupe target to a more fitting duplicate (the one I eventually chose).

Now, I could've waited for the 5th re-open vote that would've inevitably been cast, before I'd have inevitably closed it as a dupe, using my golden hammer.

Instead, I decided to speed up the process a little.

In doing so, I prevented one user from basically *wasting* a close-vote.
I also wasted my own reopen vote, but I'm pretty sure I'm not gonna need it, any way, as I see no way to make that question not a duplicate.

Now, I would only condone this if the question was only **one** vote away from being re-opened. Then your golden vote doesn't carry any extra weight. Same for the opposite scenario, assuming the 4 existing close-votes are dupe votes.

If a question had only 1 reopen-vote, and you reopen-hammered then close-hammered it, well, that's just sketchy.

---

Now, you raise a concern about trust...
It's easy for me to say you can trust me to do what I think is best for the site. That said, you don't just get a gold badge. I like to think it's an indication I have at least *some* idea of how the tag works.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying it's fine since you saved another user's reopen vote and saved your own time as well? That seems reasonable. Minor points, if you want to edit the target list, you can just edit it, you don't need to reopen and then close again. Also, I said nothing about trust as far as judging whether the question should be closed as a dupe or not. A gold tag badge gives you that. My question was about annulling other's votes, which doesn't seem to follow from earning a gold tag badge.

Comment: Yea, I considered editing the dupe list, but (meta) questions that are one vote away from being re-opened generally get re-opened regardless. Editing the target list seemed kinda futile to me.

Comment: Sure, that seems reasonable enough. Would you care to address the symmetric case as well? That one's quite interesting, since it lets me insta reopen if I close it in time as a dupe.

Comment: Well, considering you're basically just speeding up the process by not waiting for that last re-open vote, I don't really see the harm.

Comment: No, I'm taking about casting the last *close* vote and then reopening it. That''s not just speeding up the process, right? If I wait for it to be closed normally, it may not get closed as a dupe, which means I can't reopen single-handedly. But if I hammer it, I can reopen it myself. I'll see if I can make that aspect clearer in my question, since that seems to be unclear to a lot of users.

Comment: I'm not sure how dupe-hammering a question with 4 "off-topic" votes would register? Does it get closed as a dupe, or as off-topic, then? I agree that that case is rather dubious.

Comment: it would be dupe closed in that case, hammer takes precedence

Comment: Then I'd personally call that abuse.

Comment: The hammer will definitely close it as a dupe (at least on Main). Yeah, I think (2) is abusive as well, but it's very unclear to me why it's substantially different than (1) In both cases the last vote is cast in bad faith, i.e. I don't believe that vote is the correct vote, and it's being done with the express purpose of saving other's time/votes. In (2) I would be saving 2 other reopen votes since I *sincerely* believe that the question should be open. It does seem that either both should be ok, or neither.

Comment: The only reason there's any difference in those two scenarios is you're putting the question into a state such that you can instantly reopen it, where as if you did nothing and let the 5th vote get cast naturally, you wouldn't have been able to hammer it open. That's definitely abusive, where the alternative you would have been able to hammer it open anyway

Comment: Well, I think the abuse is in preventing the question from being closed in a manner you can't singlehandedly undo. If it has 4 dupe votes, it'll end up closed as a dupe, which you can unilaterally revert any way. If it has 4 off-topic votes, you're gaming the system to wipe out 4 votes you normally wouldn't be able to undo.

Comment: What is the motivation around "saving" close votes? I'm quite confused on that.

Comment: @KevinB Ah, ok. So if a question already has sufficient votes for it to get closed as a dupe (which would only need 1 such vote on main), then hammering and reopening it would be fine? Of course, this means that I'm assuming that the hypothetical last close voter would close as dupe. So by that logic, if a question already has 2 dupe close votes, I can hammer, and reopen it?

Comment: @Makoto: One can only cast a close-vote on a certain question, once. Same for re-open votes. If I prevent someone from "wasting" a vote, because I was planning to cast the opposite (hammer) vote, then that user still has the option to cast said vote after my hammer vote, where he wouldn't have had that option if I'd have waited.

Comment: @cigien exactly, though... on SO with it only requiring 3 votes to close, I'd probably avoid doing this anyway... for self serving reasons. essentially, I'd rather wait for the 3rd vote to fall so that i can nullify 3 votes rather than 2.

Comment: @Cerbrus:  There's no waste.  The vote is still eligible to be cast.  The question may be more of impact - there's a whole lot more impact in closing the last vote than in the first vote - but the vote itself isn't completely removed from play in this instance.  With that I'm not really sure what the aim is; you may have a workaround or a workflow in place for a scenario which doesn't align with what needs to happen, and that's somewhat concerning.

Comment: @Makoto: If someone else casts that 5th reopen-vote, they can't reopen-vote any more after I close it. By casting that 5th vote myself, I give someone else the option of going against my hammer, where they wouldn't have had that option if I'd waited. What I find concerning is that you're basically stating there's malicious intent at play here, instead of trying to understand the reasoning.

Comment: Hmm, I still don't get it. Yes (2) is a more impactful action than (1), but that's the only difference. In both cases, the last vote is being cast in bad faith. The fact that the intention is good (i.e. putting a post into the state one believes it should be in) is neither here nor there. Obviously, the system allows both options, and your argument for why (1) is ok is borderline at best. In your own words, you took actions that let you put the post in the state you desired. I don't doubt in the least that you did this with the best of intentions, but by that metric, (2) should be ok as well.

Comment: Depends on the preceding votes for (2). If it has 4 off-topic votes, you're gaming the system, and putting the post in a state you wouldn't normally have been able to. You're basically using a dupe hammer to cancel 4 off-topic votes, which is different from using a dupe hammer to cancel 4 dupe-votes, as that's something the dupe hammer can do any way.

Comment: But you literally did the same thing by casting the last reopen vote: you put the post in a state you wouldn't normally have been able to. Sure, you're claiming that the post would have been reopened anyway, and that you're saving votes. But I could make the same argument for the other case, i.e. the post would have gotten closed *and* gotten the necessary reopen votes anyway, and so my use of the dupe hammer saved those votes, along with the last close vote. In both cases, we'd be predicting the future votes cast on the post, which seems dicey.

Comment: Except that on closure, you can't predict whether or not you'll be able to re-open it with the dupe hammer, and for the 4 off-topic votes, it's very likely you won't be able to unhammer it if you wait for the 5th vote. If you then hammer and unhammer it, you're using the _dupe_ hammer to undo _off-topic_ votes.

Comment: like most other cases of moderation... it's a case-by-case situation. I wouldn't complain about a flag being raised in any case of this occurring

Comment: @Cerbrus So by that logic, if a post was closed for some reason other than a duplicate, and it has reopen votes, then casting the last reopen vote (and then close-hammering it) would not be acceptable, since presumably the reopen votes were cast in opposition to the off-topic closure?

Comment: In that situation, you still aren't putting yourself at an advantage or doing anything you wouldn't have been able to do if you had waited

Comment: Geez... Closing and reopening are not the same! You can't just mirror the rules. Have I not been clear about the distinction of putting the post in a state that may not possible to achieve if you let someone else cast that last vote? In re-opening, there's only one possible outcome if the vote goes through: It's _open_. Closure has a lot more states, of which only _one_ can be undone with a gold badge.

Comment: @Cerbrus Ok, so you're saying that an action is fine so long as the resulting state of the post would be the same as it would be if someone else took that action? I don't entirely agree, but you've made your view point clear. Anyway, I seem to have worn out your patience with this comment thread, so I won't continue it any further. Thanks for the clarifications, and apologies for not getting your point sooner.

Comment: It's past midnight here, that ain't helping xD

Comment: You're saying you've done it to avoid wasting someone else's vote. That your action would have been to close the post no matter who cast the last reopen vote. But aren't you wasting the 4 reopen votes that were cast by re-closing it?

Comment: @Scratte are you saying I'm not allowed to use my dupe hammer to re-open a duplicate closure I disagree with, or close a re-opened dupe, when I disagree with the closure? What you're describing there is just the standard process...

Comment: No, I'm saying that the argument is a bit.. strange.

Comment: No, you're claiming I'm wasting 4 user's votes by using my gold badge to close a question: _"But aren't you wasting the 4 reopen votes that were cast by re-closing it?"_, but that's just how it works...

Answer (score -2):

Votes being annulled because of a reopen is a pretty *exceptional* case, and I would strongly argue that in the case you cite, there's nothing really exceptional going on there.

So no, I wouldn't think in this exact instance that doing this would be OK.  There would have to be some kind of justification for the move, and normal gold-badge holders wouldn't normally be moved to reopen a question like that in most circumstances.

I would give the benefit of the doubt to someone who may have read something too fast, or if the coffee/tea hadn't taken effect just yet; I've made some mistakes in closing and reopening dupes, and it could be attributed to that.  Simply leaving the question the way you found it - as in, if it was originally closed, leave it closed after you're done; if it was originally open, reopen it when you're done - would be the best approach.

Comment: Just to clarify, since it may have been unclear in the question, I'm not asking about the specific instance. It was meant *only* as an example, since describing the situation may not have been clear enough. But IIUC, you're saying that in general this is not ok, if done intentionally?

Comment: I would prefer it be done by a diamond moderator, honestly.  Even I haven't done something like this on purpose in my years, and with all of the gold tag badges I have here, although I have seen it done by diamond mods.

Comment: Yeah, a mod doing this would not be an issue obviously. Fortunately, there now appear to be two answers to my question, each saying the opposite thing. I guess we can just let the votes on the answers reveal what the consensus is. I had never thought of this kind of action before, but if it turns out that this is ok, there are *many* instances on main where this would come in handy.

Comment: I've also seen this done by other gold badge owners. More on SO main than on Meta, but that's got more to do with the quantity of questions and badges on the sites, than policy.

Comment: @Cerbrus Oh, that's very interesting. I can't recall ever seeing this happen on Main. Maybe it just happens a lot less frequently in the tags I follow. Or a lot more frequently in the ones you follow, of course, or something in between :)

Comment: @cigien:  This may be why I lean more towards normal behavior and normal circumstances.  Thinking on it, the issue that I'd have is if it would be "normal" for a user with dupe-hammer privileges to want to reopen or close the question.  If it doesn't really make a lot of sense to take the first action, then the second action is based on the exceptional behavior of the first action.  Diamond mods handle exceptions, so it fits more in their wheelhouse than ours.  I wouldn't exactly be surprised if it *happens* on main, but that doesn't make it *right*.

Answer (score -3):

> Similarly, can I use my hammer to annul a bunch of close votes that I think are incorrect (by close-hammering with a bogus target) and then instantly reopening it?

Now this seems like an easy way to get into controversial situations. Why hurry? This feels like meta-gaming around system rules. I would suggest you to simply follow such a post and check on your notifications later in the day. The end result would be the same, but obtained through a much less questionable series of actions.

Comment: I can only really agree with your last couple of sentences here.  The ultimate outcome would be the same if one decided to watch the question for activity or follow-up on a moderation action (like dupe closure), and that'd be less dubious.  What I don't disagree with though is the notion that we're not meant to be talking about stuff like this here on Meta.  That's its purpose.

Comment: @Makoto hmm that's not quite the meaning I meant to convey, maybe even my wording itself is muddy, I'll edit that out since right now I can't wrap my head around expressing it better.

Comment: I'm confused by this answer. Yes, it's controversial, and feels a bit like gaming the system. But that's why I'm asking the question on Meta, to see what the community thinks. I'm quite happy to go with whatever the consensus is. Also, I already made it clear (I hope) the advantages option (2) has over waiting.

Comment: @cigien well, I guess I don't see it as a good enough advantage to make it worth confusing the post history and possibly other users like that. Would such a situation happen often enough to make a significant difference? It seems rather uncommon to me.

Comment: Being able to put a post into a state that I think it should be in, while reducing the amount of curation others have to put in, seems like a worthwhile advantage. This may not be a common situation, in fact I didn't even realize this was a possible technique till I saw the timeline I mentioned in the question. But if it turns out it's ok (currently the consensus seems to be that it's not) then I would start doing it myself.