# Why do comment upvotes not give reputation?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, reputation

Even if only a little bit, shouldn't good comments warrant an increase in reputation?

Comment: Make them answers to earn rep, if they're really that good and don't replicate existing answers!

Comment: Does a comment like "Could you share your version number?", that multiple people agree with, really deserve reputation?

Comment: Yeeees!!! (*depending on how many upvotes this comment gets*)

Comment: But seriously, no because of what the above to (useful) comments said.

Comment: @codeMagic If such applies as stated with your 1st comment, do you think, we should have a tool to turn comments into answers (not by copying as your own one of course), as we already have vice versa?

Comment: You mean I could earn rep with a comment that says this post should be a comment not an answer?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ummm....no

Comment: @codeMagic Well, so we're agree here.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/reputation-for-comments, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147622/why-dont-useful-comments-reward-reputation, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82685/should-comment-upvotes-reward-reputation, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3053/why-dont-we-get-reputation-for-upvotes-on-comments… Lots of people seem to be confused about the point of a comment.

Comment: cue the tired "comments are second class citizens" spiel

Comment: I do not understand why this question has so many downvotes? It is a legit good question to me!

Comment: @User81862311 According to the message you see when hovering your mouse over the upvote/downvote button, upvote/downvote should be determined with respect to two points: clearness and usefulness. Since this question asks personal opinions, inherently it is difficult to judge if or not the question is useful. However, I believe the question itself it crystal-clear. Thus I suspect the downvoters clicked the button just to say "I don't think so." (Or they thought the OP was too short? I agree with the point.)

Comment: I also think that comment should be giving some *income*. It may not be an Answer *per se*, but it can still provide a great help to the community.

Comment: This would be like viewing sports journalists as great athletes just because they're reporting on sports. They're not the ones on the field.

Comment: @If_You_Say_So It doesn't show any "research effort", one of the criteria for a good question.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

No.

Comments are second-class citizens here on Stack Overflow and other sites in the Stack Exchange network, and votes on them are merely a measure of agreement, rather than a measure of usefulness.

If your comment [*is an answer*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments) and you want reputation for it, expand on it and post it as an answer.

It's as simple as that: comments are to be used to critique or ask for clarification from the author and nothing more.

Comment: Not to mention there is no comment downvote so there is no way to show disagreement with a comment other than posting another comment.

Comment: That's why one used to get 10 times less points for a useful comment, or 25 less points in case it's marked as useful solution. A comment is often an altruistic contribution to point the other guys in the right direction. Perhaps a moderator should delete non constructive chat-like comments, but I believe useful comments deserve rep.

Comment: I think that comments should be giving something at least in return, and the argument like *write it as an answer if it is* does not really seem to be explaining the rejection of this proposal.. simply, because comment may *not* be the Answer *per se*, but it can still provide a great help to the community.

Comment: You can get something in return by Edit-ing an existing Answer instead of commenting on it, to provide the additional information, assuming you haven't reached the reputation limit from doing so.

Answer (score 3):

I've been wondering about something similar (which brought me to this question). I agree that in the existing sense of reputation, which should provide a measure of knowledge in a particular subject area, comments shouldn't be rewarded.

However I would really like to see a measure of a user's moderation ability, involvement, and/or personability. This could be very useful when it comes time to vote for moderators. So food for thought might be a new type of reputation for only moderation activities. In this class comments seems to fit well.

Comment: With no downvotes on comments to counterbalance this, I think you will need to bring a LOT more info to your proposal here

Comment: for example (to down voters) saying why this post deserves a down vote is something that I look for in moderators. users should have incentive to comment in order to provide more insight to the poster. constructive criticism is often more informative than agreement.

Comment: @Patrice indeed, thank you for the comment, no sarcasm intended ;)

Comment: also.... you say "moderators"... but we're ALL moderators. you mean diamond mods I assume? Since diamond mods take care of things like rollback wars, sock puppets, etc, why does "you leave a comment when you downvote" should have ANY influence there?

Comment: i suppose my view of moderators is skewed then. Beyond the maintenance work I expect moderators to be role models of the community. when a commentor does what the hover text 'this comment adds something useful to the post' says then its a good measure of what I want representing my community.

Comment: but that whole point of view of moderators is what WE should be doing. Not diamond mods. And with this in mind, looks like you're just trying to re-hash the super old "force comments on downvote" debate... which never really goes anywhere productive

Comment: agreed. i was hoping this might bring a different perspective but understand how it is heard digresses into that.

Answer (score -4):

I think the logic of the system is that you get rep only from creating useful, productive content. "Community work" and similar give everything (badges), but the only way to get rep is that you create useful content on the main site.

Comment: Look at the accepted answer here. That answer is correct. This answer doesn't add anything new to this (OLD) question...

Comment: If only that were true. But plenty of useful productive content goes on without a single upvote and thus no reputation awarded for it.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, it adds - it is essentially different than the accepted one. The essence of this answer that to get rep, you need to provide work. The essence of the accepted answer is that comments are second-level citizens. These are similar, but far from being the same.

Comment: @Gimby I never said that the voters are fair (check the score of this answer - probably they did not even try to read it and voted down for hostility). The same goes, with a lesser extent, also on the main site. But, the answer details the logic of the system (which is imho pretty okay), not its practice.

Comment: I didn't say this is the same. I said that this answer _"doesn't add anything new to this (OLD) question"_.

Comment: @Cerbrus And I say that it adds. Undervaluing productive work is something what the SE tries to avoid, but metas try to catalyze :-)