# Is the practice of deleting comments helpful?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that some users remove their comments *ex post*.  When back and forth took place in the comment section, the remaining comments lack context.

Is the point of this that we want to encourage users to post, an objective which is furthered by knowing they can permanently retract statements at a later time?

Comment: If a comment leads to an edit of the question or answer, it may become obsolete. I try to follow that up by removing the comment, as it no longer is relevant or even may confuse future readers. (And follow-up comments by the OP may need deleting as well.)

Comment: Very often my comments go down a purely temporary, conversational path. I'm just probing for more info, trying to help the OP work out what the real issue might be, brainstorming, etc. It's purely chat and serves no permanent purpose. It actually helps the site to clean these up afterwards.

Comment: There is, indeed, a semi-bad thing that can happen if you _don't_ delete comments: see here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments

Answer (score 53):

Comments are temporary post-it notes, used for clarification purposes.  That is their only function.  If you want content to be (semi) permanent, then you need to put it in a question or answer, in accordance with the content policies currently in effect.

Comment: I understand there's this lofty notion of current content policy, but I can tell you, that's **not** even remotely close to how people use the comments. I often find *gems of information* in the comment section. Let's be *realistic*, most of that content is never going to be edited into the Q or A. You have to be dumb to think otherwise. And if ever comes the day when a moderator'll say "in accordance with our policies, due to the temporary nature of comments, we'll simply purge the old ones" I will get a magnum, aim right between the eyes and pull the trigger, knowing I did the right thing.

Comment: Mods don't delete useful, on-topic comments anyway, unless they're buried in a sea of useless chaff.  Keep comments on-topic, and you won't have this problem.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I recently saw moderators moving very useful comments to chat. In my eyes, that's like deletion, an abomination. So I had good reasons to write all this.

Comment: @BartoszKP: here's one example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26995382/type-signatures-that-never-make-sense/26995560#comment42649963_26995560

Comment: @BartoszKP See [this Data Explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/147890/most-popular-comments-ever) for comments with more than 500 votes. Some are simply funny quips, but others do contain useful information that has never been incorporated into the associated post.

Comment: @BartoszKP Ah, it seems like you're referring to Karoly's second comment that "I recently saw moderators moving very useful comments to chat." I didn't notice that, and was only addressing the point that "most of that content is never going to be edited into the Q or A." Obviously, we can't prove either way that *most* useful comments stay as comments, but I think a Data Explorer query like the one I linked to can show that there is a significant amount of useful content in comments, especially when you consider that it hasn't been moved into the post content after hundreds of votes.

Comment: That's actually quite close to what I meant. Thank you. The gist is really just: "You can say that comments are ephemeral, but in practice they are NOT.". and "If the whole presupposition is false, you shouldn't base any actions on it".  @BartoszKP: And now, if you will excuse me I will stop the conversation at this point, because I don't want to continue it with someone who degrades the whole thing to an "erratic ranting"...

Comment: The comment thread you cited is lovingly preserved here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65212

Answer (score 17):

Comments are not meant to be permanent. If a user decides to delete their comment, sometimes another user engaged in a discussion will also delete their comment as a courtesy. This will avoid the "out of context" issue you're referring to. It is particularly effective if it's about an edit, downvote or criticism of a post that is no longer relevant. The user may remove their comment to avoid confusing on-lookers.

Comment: And if you delete your own comments in a thread as no longer relevant, you can flag the other user's comments related to yours as 'obsolete'.  Most often, rather than just selecting 'obsolete', I'll choose 'Other' and then start the comment 'Obsolete' (or whatever is appropriate) and give a quick summary of why, because I understand that the moderators do not get all that much context for flagged comments, so if it is not self-evident why the comment is no longer relevant, the flag may be declined whereas the explanation typically makes it clearer to them why the flag is relevant.

Comment: Like for _".. delete their comment as a courtesy"_. Good example of common sense. However, it seems there is no way to know a comment above yours has been deleted except checking periodicaly your comments.. :/ _as a courtesy_ how could I notify the other participants when I'm about to delete my comment ?

Comment: @fsintegral: ironically enough, by @-commenting at them. I tend to do this with a note that "I'm about to delete my comments above (and this one, in a few minutes)" and then give an hour or so (though I occasionally forget, and come back to it a week later with a facepalm).

Comment: If you delete an @-comment does the person's notification disappear? If so then one hour doesn't seem anywhere near long enough. Some people don't check SO every day. Some might go on holiday for 3 weeks...

Comment: @IanGoldby It doesn't, from what I experienced (I remember getting a notification and the comment wasn't there, presumable because the person decided to write something completely different, like we were typing simultaneously and my response invalidated what they wanted to write).

Answer (score 7):

I didn't know we could flag comments for deletion when they fall out of context (and become noise after a previous comment deletion or post edit)

Thanks @JonathanLeffler.
I've read a lot of comments recently and didn't understand the chain of ideas (like first three comments answering to a user that appears nowhere on the entire page, and further comments making fun of him.. => Noise ?)

Everything required to answer a question (*"required !"*, I didn't said *"related"*) should belong to an answer, not comments. I do try to read comments whenever possible, but it's not always the case, so I'm assuming the average user don't bother reading XX comments of every posts. SE/SO also put valuable comments on top by default, that somewhat mess up the chain of ideas. So, comments are not suitable/not recommended for discussion (as stated by the help center)

Anyway, *any* user is free to delete his comment (or leave it there). Then, *the community* is also free to flag a comment asking for deletion (just knew that though). What seems not possible is preventing comment deletion (unless Moderation locks the post? — there are indeed comments that contains extremely valuable piece of information)

*I would advise* to write valuable/useful piece of information in an *informal* way — if it's inside a *"not an answer"* comment, that is, not related to any previous comment — whenever possible.

I also think that *"Your question appears unclear"*-like in comments could be removed if OP's question is correctly edited; this just adds noise and confusion for further readers...

I'm just unsure whether Moderation is OK to be tasked to delete "out of context" comments..(?)

Comment: If you see comments answering a user that no longer appears to have a comment in the conversation, then there's a high probability (but not 100% probability) that those comments no longer add anything useful to the question or answer, and such comments should be flagged for deletion (obsolete, too chatty, or another option as seems most appropriate).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Agreed, but unless you flag every single comment, or run into an extra thoughtful moderator, this will result in just the one comment that you flag being removed. Is there any better way to flag the entire comment thread?

Comment: @JirkaHanika: I note in one comment that I am about to flag a number of comments with same flag and the reason why, and then flag the other comments quickly with no explanation. I've done that for 4 or 5 comments on a single question or answer on occasion.