# What should I do with comments I made that are due to my typo?

Tags: discussion

I found a question about SQL joins that was very useful: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1757260/3271599) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1757302/3271599).

When I tried the answer, it didn't work for me as I had hoped, and I posted [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757260/simplest-way-to-do-a-recursive-self-join-in-sql-server/1757302?noredirect=1#comment42771368_1757302) seeking a clarification. The answerer responded, and there was some back and forth.

Now I realize that I did not implement the answer correctly, due to a simple typo I made.

Should I delete my comments? The small exchange adds nothing to the answer for future users, but I can only delete my own comments, not the ones in reply to me. Should I just post another comment saying it was due a typo?

Comment: What about deleting the question? Or were answers given pointing out it's due to a typo? (Also could you post a link that we can inspect what's actually in question please)

Comment: I will clarify my question - the question and answer are fine, it's my comment that's a problem.
The "a comment" is a link to the comment I made, but it is hard to see.

Comment: _"but it is hard to see"_ Yes, one of the critiques about the _new design_ here. I'd just remove that comment, don't care that it makes the other comment obsolete.

Comment: You can delete your comments if you want to, and if you do, you can flag the other guy's comments as obsolete.  That might not be worth a moderator's time, so I wouldn't do it, but the option is there.

Comment: On deleting comments: <http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277655/is-the-practice-of-deleting-comments-helpful>

Answer (score 1):

As per the suggestions of Sam I am, Pat W. and... [unicode] (just kidding, 
πάντα ῥεῖ), I have deleted my comments from the answer.