# My question doesn't have an 'answer'. How do I write it off?

Tags: discussion

This question is close to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298649/what-should-i-do-with-my-question-which-doesnt-really-have-an-answer-but-has-a), but not quite.

I have a few open questions that don't 'technically' have answers, but with the few questions I have, I'd like to write them off.

How do I do that? Do I put down what I 'think' is the right approach then accept it? Some of my questions don't have even comments that provide answers, so I'm a bit lost as to what to do in regards to these open issues.

Comment: I'm not clear on whether you actually found a solution to these questions or not.

Comment: @BSMP not all of them. Some yes, some no. Some of them may never have answers, so I'm wondering how to close both situations out properly.

Comment: If you _really_ have an answer, then post it, but don't just write something as an answer to have at least one answer on your question, even though it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @Tom so leaving some questions open is reasonable in the case of no answer that finalizes things then?

Comment: If the question that doesn't have an answer isn't drawing any negative attention then there's no reason to do anything.

Comment: *"so leaving some questions open is reasonable in the case of no answer that finalizes things then? "* You can also delete your questions if you don't think they should be kept.

Comment: If you talking about approach, it is off topic. You can discuss it in the corresponding [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) group.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping open questions around is not a problem.

If you still want to do something about them you have several options:

- If question has answer in comments - feel free to convert it to complete answer and accept.
- If question has no real answers, you are not interested in it, and not many views (<100?) feel free to delete. If there are many views - consider bounty as getting answer on a popular question can pay off bounty in upvotes.
- If there is no answer and you still interested - add bounty. If you for whatever reason don't want to do that - you can try to "cheat" by improving the question (it will bump it to front page for short time).
- If there is no answer and you found one - post answer.

If you decide to keep question after looking at it see if some editing can improve it. Often you gain insights on what a good question is and you'll find that old questions could be missing some useful info or can get style improved. As side effect questions will get a short visibility bump to be on the home page.

If you decide to delete questions remember that deleted questions still count against question ban - deleting zero and lower scored questions only hides them from view. Improving would be better if you have measurable number of zero and lower scored questions (less likely to apply to 1K+ users).