# What to do if the answer is a comment of a very short answer?

Tags: discussion

I have the following problem: I asked a question on SO ([Instantiate Child Object with Parent config or 'downcast parent to child'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29032492/instantiate-child-object-with-parent-config-or-downcast-parent-to-child)), got a very short answer that did not help me at all, but then the author of this answer explained it in the comments and with that, made the answer the one I would like to accept.

Now marking this answer as the correct one feels strange for me, as other folks might find my question when having a similar problem and then they might not look into the comments and just don't understand the "correct answer".

I have read both meta discussions: [Answerers who only use comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments) and [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments), but they seem to only cover posts where the answer is in the comments of the question.

I could just post an answer myself, quoting the user but as he is (also) very new on SO I do not want him to have a "bad experience" and steal him his reputation and credit.

As a solution I thought of just editing his comment into his answer, but this approach was predominantly rejected https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7370270

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments are ephemeral. They're for clarifying things. If the comment is an important part of the answer, I would suggest editing the answer to include it. (I would, but I'm not sure I really understand it, so will leave it to someone who definitely does). I'm at a bit of a loss to explain why this suggestion was rejected, aside from perhaps needing a bit more rewording to make it more answer than comment.  (So perhaps adding a comment to *that* effect might do the trick!)

If the answer helped you (most) then accept it. (Regardless of quality)

Any answer that is objectively 'good' you should upvote. (This can be the one you accepted, post edit)

It is my opinion that whilst the answer you linked to may be *right* it is *not* an objectively good answer without that additional detail.

Comment: ok, I think that sounds reasonable! And thanks for the help in the SO question! :)

Answer (score 0):

> ...made the answer the one *I would like to accept*

So accept it then.
It's your question, and your privilege to accept it, based on the logic and reasons you would accept an answer.

IMO you shouldn't accept it because you feel obliged, or because the user got you your answer in "comments", a comment is not an answer even if it helped/answered the question - but again, that is your decision.

As your suggested edit was rejected, suggest to the answerer to add their comment text to their answer and then you'll accept - on the basis it's mostly/also the comment which "answered" the question so need to be in their "answer".

If the answerer doesn't move the comment text to their answer, in 10 hours, a day, whatever you feel is appropriate, then feel free to take the text and make a new answer of your own.

While the question was yours to be answered, it's not "only" about you or the answerer, it's also about providing a resource for other users who might happen by the question/answer.
So it's in everyone's interest to make a viable answer for everyone to easily find and it be a decent "Q&A".