# Should I post my correctly guessed comment as an answer?

Tags: support, answers, comments

I'm currently indecisive whether to post an answer to a question which I could answer by guessing correctly. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967381/searching-through-relationships-and-date-in-laravel#29967381) is the question I'm talking about.

I've come up with a possible cause for the problem the user had from experience. I didn't want to post a possibly incorrect answer so I suggested an edit in the comments which turned out to be the solution.

Should I now post my answer as a proper answer, or entice the original asker to post his modified code and self-accept it? Or just leave the situation as it is (leaving it at zero answers)?

Comment: Answer it yourself. That is the best option.

Comment: See also my comment in [Answerers who only use comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286645/2564301) where I stated I was only guessing -- and then got told not to do that!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you should post it as an answer. You should also remove your comment once the answer is posted as it is obsolete at that point.

An answer is always better than a comment. It is easier for the original poster to see solutions. It is easier for future visitors to see solutions. Comments can be hidden if the comment thread gets long. Comments can be removed fairly easily.

I think you should post it versus encouraging the asker to update and post. It is simply less work for you. If you ask the OP to edit their question, post an answer, and then accept the answer, you are expecting them to follow a much longer chain than you would have to by simply posting the answer yourself.

Comment: Also, if a question has no (upvoted or accepted) answer, it can't ever be used as a dupe target, even though the answer might be right there in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you should answer it yourself and get the reward; otherwise it is open for someone else to post your answer as a community Wiki answer as described here:
[Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)

Comment: No need for making it CW as the OP(of this question) has himself solved the issue, not someone else/with the help of someone or some other users

Comment: @CoolGuy I think you misread. I suggest that *someone else* could come along and make a wiki if the OP did not post an answer; not that the OP should do it. It was a veiled threat of what someone else may do.

Comment: oh, My bad. In that case, it is fine.

Answer (score 2):

To be polite I first ask the OP if they mind if move the comment to the answer and ask them if they'll accept it there. Everyone has said yes, and accepted the answer posted right away.

If you just move the response to the answer w/o any interaction with the poster they may not realize you've updated to an answer.

I haven't deleted the dup comments afterwards, as suggested above, but that is a good idea.

Comment: The OP will get a "new answer" notification when you move your comment to an answer since it is a new answer. If they do not pay attention to notifications they won't know there is a new answer but then again if they don't pay attention to notifications they won't know that you've commented either, so...

Comment: Sure. But will they be diligently following up on SO, *after* they have their answer all locked up? I don't know. I like to ask. It's a gentle reminder to please accept the answer.