# Should an answer be edited to include the correct answer from another's comment?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

I asked a rather simple C++ question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996338/pointer-returned-from-a-function-isnt-valid) and got an response that didn't fix my actual problem. However, a comment on that response, from a different user, pointed out that I was making a language mistake, and showed me what my real error was.

I didn't mark that response as the answer because it was about a side effect of my real problem, not the problem itself. A different, second commenter requested that I mark that response as the correct answer, I gave my reasons why I didn't feel it was correct, so the commenter edited the answer to include the comment.

In the past what I've done is to ask the first commenter to make their own post, and then I'd mark it as the answer. But what I'm wondering is, is that good form to edit someone else's incorrect/less useful answer with someone else's correct answer? Should I accept this edit, request that the first commenter make their own, separate answer, or just leave it all be? The first answer wasn't bad, per-say, it just didn't help me.

**Update:** There's been some confusion in answers I've received. The user who edited the answer is neither the author of the answer, nor the author of the comment that actually made the answer. *User 1* made a response with an incorrect answer. *User 2* made a comment with the correct answer. *User 3* then edited *User 1*'s answer to include *User 2*'s answer.

Comment: I would tell the person who solved the issue to phrase it in an answer.

Comment: This really seems to be two questions. The title asks whether User 3 did a good thing that we want to encourage. I think the answer to that is "No", but I'm not that worried. The body, on the other hand, asks what you should do, given that User 3 has done what he did. Which one do you really want discussed here?

Comment: @abarnert Kind of both. I've never had that happen before, and it was more of a "I don't think User 3 did a good thing, but I wanted to hear what SO thinks about it, and what would be the logical thing to do in response"

Answer (score 4):

If it is correct answer - accept it.

There are many reasons why one would be an [Answerers who only use comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments), or prefer edits over creating own answer.

One reason why not to create new answer is original answer is 95% there and creating new complete answer would mean essentially copying whole existing answer and adding one word. This may be reasonable for old/abandoned answers (especially if code change is required), but this case is new and all authors participated.

Note that commenter seem to explicitly prefer keeping that answer instead of creating new one, so asking for new separate answer would be strange:

> added in the edit including that comment. Once accepted by @Peter it should thus be possible to consider it as the answer

Comment: Except that the commenter who "prefer keeping that answer instead of creating new one" isn't the one who made the initial answer or who made the comment that was the answer. It's a third, random user.

Answer (score 4):

I think ideally, you'd want the person who actually solved your problem to write the answer so you can accept it—or, if he's not going to do so, to put his solution into a Community Wiki answer (as with [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)) and accept that.

If the helpful person has already edited someone else's answer to be correct, what would that change? Clearly, he doesn't mind losing credit for his work. And anyone searching for your question later will be nicely served by the edited answer. So, as long as the person whose answer he edited doesn't mind having his answer improved (and getting more rep), who's being hurt if you just accept the edited answer?

Even if it's a third person who did the edit, who's being hurt? It's basically the same case for everyone involved. Unless, of course, you think the commenter was going to come back and write his own answer. In that case, definitely wait for him to do so.

I don't think we should be encouraging this kind of third-party edit, but we really aren't encouraging them—the editor isn't the one getting the rep or any other form of credit.

So, if you:

- Suspect that the commenter actually does want to write his own answer and hasn't had time yet,
- Are seriously worried that the original answerer is going to reject the edit, or
- Are bothered that the answered doesn't deserve the rep…

… then ignore the edit (or even revert it) and write and accept a Community Wiki answer (or, in the first case, wait for the commenter's answer).

Otherwise, I'd just accept it.

Comment: That's the thing, it isn't the person who made the answer in the comments who made the edit. It's a random, third user that came along later and decided to combine the two

Comment: @cost: I'm not sure how much that changes things, but I'll edit it to explain why…

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the best thing to do would be commenting your own answer saying "I got it wrong, user x got it right". It's useless and quite dishonest to just copy another user's answer, cause someone could upvote you and you would get the "glory" instead of the one who found the answer.