# Is providing an answer in comment area a good practice?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

There are several times I saw people giving solutions to the problem in the comment area. Some of them later provide an answer themselves, others can be converted to answers by making it "community wiki" as suggested in this post: [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments).

But my question is, is it a good practice to provide answers in the comment section? I know, it may be helpful for getting some extra badges like commentator, pundit. But I don't think, it is the right way to achieve that. So what else can be the reason, why do the people (with high reputation) provide the solution in the comment section instead of posting it as an answer? Why should I (or why shouldn't I) do the same?

Comment: Some people don't have the time to write the answer out in full or can't be bothered. I normally do it when I'm on a mobile like now.

Comment: Just for kicks: People tend to answer in the comments when they want to help, but don't think the question deserves a full answer or don't have time to offer a full answer.

Comment: Sometimes the asker just doesn't know the right word to search for.  I could write a full answer, or say "hey, you're looking for an _assembler_" which should be enough for them to help themselves.

Comment: "Is it a good practice?"  Not really, but it isn't necessarily a bad practice.

Comment: Comments by their nature are ephemeral and may disappear, so while answering in a comment may be helpful, it isn't something we should make a habit of.

Comment: I think these comments prove that the SE staff and mods don't hate fun nearly as much as advertised

Comment: Lookin at you @shog

Comment: It happens. Generally when the question isn't clear enough to know for certain you're answering correctly - I don't feel comfortable just putting an educated guess answer, so I stick to the comments. That opens the door to "accidentally" answer the question in the process of obtaining more clarity from the OP. Depending on who did the most work in that process I either answer myself or invite the person who asked the question to self-answer.

Comment: I will provide clues, hoping others will pick up on it (op included), versus embarrassing myself by providing an Answer and seeming like one of those rep you-know-what things.

Comment: I love that all of the answers for this question are in the comments so far

Comment: Near dupe of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments, based on the answers.

Answer (score -2):

Ok @Zach, I will provide an official answer.

Many experienced solution providers (real or self-proclaimed) are trying to help other users while not seeming like all they want are points. Thus, they leave tips in comments. Plus it is more fun in a way. Help and move on with less back-and-forth and the dreaded "I just got married to your Question" problem by providing an Answer and the baggage that may invoke.

I think everyone knows what that means, the baggage. If not, give a real insightful Answer to someone who just joined the technology of your favorite tag.

Sometimes, veteran Answerers, like Barmar for instance, will be like, enough already, I will just Answer the thing. Reason being, if it is not manifested in the Answer block, it doesn't exist. Even if the comments make it obvious to everyone.

But obvious to some is not obvious to all.

Is it good practice? I don't know. We are all trying to help I imagine, and some of us are trying to let others score the points or solve it on their own, versus the other extreme of never finding a question we won't answer.

Good practice is in the eye of the beholder.