# Answers in comments: Am I a jerk for answering anyway?

Tags: discussion

I know there's already exhaustive discussion on the topic of [Answerers who only use comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments) but I'm wondering if I'm a jerk for posting answers to simple questions that already have the answer in the comments.  The answer to the post above specifically mentions typos or something similar, which I totally understand closing the question in that instance, but what if it's not a typo just a really simple answer like a syntax error that the user honestly didn't know how to use correctly?

A comment there says this:

> Some time back on Meta I read an answer (from possibly Jeff) that said
>   anybody is at liberty to provide an answer from the commentary. I have
>   never done this, but I suspect it's fine. - @Gayot Fow

Does anyone have the link to the mentioned post?  I don't want to be an outcast but I want to use the site properly.  I'm afraid the types of people that ask these simple questions may not read all the comments and could miss the answer.

Comment: Oh I like the community wiki answer idea!  And I have in the past commented asking people to post as an answer but that gets tiring.  Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: Nah, as long as you flesh it out. I often post comment answers as I have rough guidance but don't want to take the time to turn it into a decent answer.

Comment: ^^ same here.  Sometmies, I just don't feel like the rep is worth it, or I'm not 100% sure I've spotted the OP's issue.  Feel free:)

Comment: And here's my first community wiki answer.  Hooray. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35063878/two-sets-of-double-quotes-batch-file-error/35069467#35069467

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure it's fine...if the question is not close-worthy.

If the original commenter doesn't answer (you might like to ping them first as a courtesy).

If you feel guilty about it (*I don't*) you can make it a Community Wiki answer and gain no rep.

Answers are useful for the future. Comments are ephemeral and likely to be deleted.

Comment: I *love* that you originally posted this as a comment.

Comment: Oh I like the community wiki answer idea! And I have in the past commented asking people to post as an answer but that gets tiring. Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: "Comments are ephemeral and likely to be deleted" - often said, but not actually the norm if you ask me. Comments are actually persistent buggers that *can* disappear, but that does not imply it is likely to happen.

Comment: Maybe not disappear as in deleted, but they definitely often get bumped for newer or higher voted comments.