# Unanswered Questions

Tags: discussion

Some Unanswered Questions really do have answers, albeit the "answers" are in COMMENTS.   (And other Unanswered Questions have Answers, and even Answers that have been voted positive).  When I select Unanswered Questions, why aren't they properly filtered?  Who is in charge of updating the status to Answered?

Comment: Side note: I assume you know that it is perfectly fine to convert comment into full answer yourself - if you find popular (by visits) "unanswered" question with such comments you can gain fame/points by providing formal answer based on comments.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov   It just would NOT be cricket to add my name as the answerer.  What is needed is a way for me to promote some comment into an answer and retain the commenters name.

Comment: Relevant link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251597

Comment: @donPablo Providing complete high quality answer requires non-trivial effort, much higher than comment. As result there is no automated way to promote comments to answers. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat have a lot of discussion on the topic as well as recommendation to go "community wiki" route if you really don't want credit for your (hopefully) significant effort in writing complete answer...

Comment: ...you are also welcome to post this as "feature-request", but make sure to read links I've added first and clarify why you believe there a lot of cases where such automatic conversion will result in high quality answers. I.e. it should be easy for you to provide links to 5-10 today's posts showing such comments to prove the need of the feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Question and *Answer* site. A question is considered no longer unanswered when it has an actual *answer* (well, it's actually a bit more complex than that). Comments may resolve the issue, but they're never "answers", since they're not in the answer box.

Sadly, some users have taken it upon themselves to post material that resolves a question in a comment. This has the effect you're experiencing: making the "unanswered" filter utterly worthless.

The person with the responsibility for "updating the status to Answered" is the person who choose to post the answer in a comment rather than an answer. They reneged on that responsibility when they put an answer in a comment.

Unfortunately, there's nothing to be done. These users don't care about other people being able to find unresolved issues.

Comment: @pnuts: Well, "nothing" that doesn't involve making a Sisyphean effort at cleanup.