# An "Answered in comments" Link

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments

To recast as a feature-request a great suggestion in an accepted META [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253048/13744178):

> [W]hy not offer the OP (or high-rep users, or both) an "Answered in comments" link to click? The goal here, I stress, is ultimately to have the question marked as "answered".

Comment: It'd be cool if a comment was apparently an answer, that the OP could move it to the answers section as an Answer. maybe not. The downside of answering in the comments is that someone else could just repost it as an answer.

Comment: This would require completely redesigning how comments work. That's a lot of work for a problem that can be solved by just posting the answer as an actual answer.

Comment: The problem posed in the link you provided is a legitimate one.  Letting comments pose as answers is the wrong solution to the problem.

Answer (score 13):

Why not? Because answers are for answers. Comments are for comments.

If the answer to a question isn't appropriate to be in the answer box, then the question isn't appropriate in the first place and should be closed.

If someone has posted an answer in a comment, do as [Robert Harvey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/7795130) suggests and

> Post an answer with the solution in the comments, and make it Community Wiki by checking the Community Wiki box.

That will achieve your same goal of the question no longer appearing as unanswered.

Comment: Often, OP writes ~"Thanks!" in a subsequent comment.  Robert Harvey's process would be streamlined if OP could accept a comment as an answer.

Comment: The OP could also delete their question. Better result, and no development needed.