# Is responding to questions with an answer when a comment would be more fitting allowed/good practice?

Tags: discussion

So, I've recently [made an answer on a low-effort question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71882505/how-to-switch-between-two-tkinter-frames/71882586#71882586), but I feel like a comment would have been more appropriate (another user did the same answer, in short, as a comment).

If I or another user with the same dilemma doesn't have comment privileges, what is the proper thing to do here? Leave an answer? Don't respond at all? Wait until you can comment, and then do it?

Comment: Related: *[Is it wrong to leave a comment to point the OP to the right direction instead of a detailed answer for simple syntax errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417450/)*

Comment: The canonical for comment privileges is *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*.

Comment: Bonus points for describing the situation with this amount of accuracy and neutrality though. Yow meta dwellers: upvote good stuff, please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either don't respond at all, or wait until you are able to comment.

Your answer is not an answer to the question. The question asked about "[How to switch between two tkinter frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71882505/how-to-switch-between-two-tkinter-frames)" and your reply talks about indentation. Surely, these two topics are unrelated. If you are unsure if the indentation in the question is the indentation they have in their actual code, you should post a comment asking for clarifications. Reserve answers only for actual solutions to the problem.

Comment: Okay, that's good to know. Thanks for the clarification.

I'm going to remove my answer in around 15 minutes (if I remember, love ADHD) and have already edited it so it says it's wrong, as there were indentation issues but it was not the cause.

Comment: @EmmaLawrence FYI if you just edit the post, you would gather downvotes since it's counted as vandalism. MIght as well delete them.

Comment: @EmmaLawrence I converted that new answer into a comment.