# Why do some people answer my question in comments?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, comments

Sometimes I ask questions on Stack Overflow, and some people don't just comment on my questions. They literally answer them. Why don't they write full answers that are displayed under the question itself?

Comment: Because often it isn't worth the effort of creating an actual answer.

Comment: Not sure if that could be a duplicate, but highly related: [Answerers who only use comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253045/6045800) (asking ***what to do*** about it and not ***why*** it happens)

Comment: @Tomerikoo Agreed, they're asking two different things

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Answerers who only use comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments)

Comment: @gnat nah, not really :)

Comment: In a way it actually does answer it... Some of the answers there explain the different motives to answer in comments

Comment: In my case it's because I don't often remember that I can answer.

Comment: Answers require a good amount of time and effort to write, comments don't. Time is usually in short supply, especially on a work day. I'm not going to pretend it is going to be any more intricate than that :)

Comment: Thanks for 6 downvotes, guys. I thought I was supposed to ask questions like these on stackoverflow    M  E  T  A
https://ibb.co/kS7yGQp

Comment: @AleksandrNovik It would help the question if you gave some examples. It's really hard to say why someone commented something on some question instead of giving some answer.

Comment: @AleksandrNovik there are 9 downvotes, actually. You are indeed supposed to ask questions, but on meta too performing research first is very much appreciated. If you don't you end up asking a question that has been asked numerous times before; do you really expect people to upvote such a question? They won't. That impacts exactly nothing though, you will forever be free to ask more of such questions and they will even likely be answered happily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's unfortunately due to the circumstance that *comments* are often conflated with *answers* in the sense that:

- They can both be upvoted
- They are visible to the OP

but with comments being a bit nicer in that:

- They can't be downvoted
- You can still comment on closed questions
- If you get it wrong, nothing adverse happens

Ultimately this is an anti-pattern; **answers belong in answers**.  If you see others providing actual answers in comments, don't hesitate to create a [Community Wiki answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/175248) with their comment (and reference the comment too) to extract the value of their comment into a medium that can actually be searched.

Comment: no need to reference comment in my opinion, a comment is not a good source. Also, I don't really like much someone quote me to backup its answer. people must assume their own answer. I think we should encourage people that think a comment should be an answer doesn't "steal" anything by making an answer. Do it. Answer. Don't wait for someone that just commented to make it. Nobody ever will say on SO "that my answer". The people will always think "Ah nice, I was lazy to make it, here take my upvote" if the answer suit them.

Comment: I'm a big fan of elevating useful answers from the comments to community wikis, and wish we'd see more of that. To me, this not only the an ideal use case for the community wiki, but also an underappreciated one. Critically, it allows answers to be marked as accepted, thus making it easier for people with the same question in the future to find useful threads—while simultaneously helping _answerers_ filter out questions that don't need further attention. I would like to spend more time doing that within my tags as a type of community maintenance, and especially for otherwise popular questions.

Answer (score 14):

Not all questions deserve an answer.

Comment: So why bother commenting?

Comment: @Makoto doesn't prevent the question from being roomba'd.

Comment: So that means that the workaround to the Roomba being somewhat ineffective at removing older or poor questions is to...misuse the comment system.  Right.  Gotcha.

Comment: But it actually does... The rule for questions older than one year with a score of <= 0 will not take effect if there's more than 1 comment...

Comment: i mean, i've hoped for it to be fixed for 10 years, kinda given up on that hope at this point. circumventing it is a far more effective option.

Comment: @Makoto it means we get questions that are not valuable for the repository of knowledge we want to build.

Comment: Everyone here is misconstruing the circumstance.  Irrespective of if the answer is in a comment block or in an actual answer, **you are still answering the question**.  If you're not keen on keeping the kinds of questions that are more debugging oriented, then let's have a constructive conversation about it and figure out what kinds of questions we actually enjoy answering.  But this misuse of the system we have doesn't do anything to fix the problem; it only perpetuates the notion that it's still OK to answer questions that we don't really want to answer as long as they're not answers.

Comment: @Makoto Maybe we should discuss *what* is an answer. I have high expectations of something that goes in the answer box. And by "high" I mean that it should help other people than the OP. "You missed a semicolon on line 3" does not seem to cover that. If that is the kind of answer we want to maintain, I think SO has failed at its mission.

Comment: We also have the expectation of the OP to do some kind of research before asking their question.  *Clearly* that's going well.  May be worth spinning up some kind of Meta conversation about this in that the expectation of answers doesn't align with the reality of answering, and we should make that known to the company, even if we're skeptical that they'll do anything about it.  Phillipe's been here long enough now to start swimming with the sharks so this'd be a golden opportunity.

Comment: @Makoto Have you considered, that maybe the question being answered isn't the problem we have with providing an answer to these kinds of posts? I personally would rather the user leave satisfied, while having the question deleted in the end than the user leave with nothing. Creating an actual answer prevents deletion and therefore isn't the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Makoto the real reason is you take time to read a bad question that show no effort, if you at least not answer in comment you completely loose your time and so to not loose all the time spend you shortcut to just comment it, simpler, faster. I didn't say it's was the good thing to do, but it's the thing we do as human.