# Mark question as complete

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, comments, accepted-answer

On many SO and SE-specific sites, there are many questions that have been resolved by comments but not an actual "answer". When looking through the "Unanswered questions" filter, this is what the majority of questions are.

Perhaps we could add a new feature where if:

1. Question has 5+ comments
2. OP has used "Thanks, resolved, worked"
3. Question has been inactive for 3 months +

Questions are marked as resolved, to save them from showing up on the feed.

Comment: Cannot be done automatically without many false negatives / false positives. Manual tagging effort is better spent on existing review queues instead.

Comment: "Thanks for your responds, that hasn't worked" -> mark as resolved.

Comment: But more seriously, if you find questions that have been answered by a comment and op has confirmed that, why not add the comments as an answer?

Comment: @BDL ok, true :)

Comment: Related on meta.SE: [What should be done with questions that have been resolved as a comment instead of an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117251/756727)

Comment: A word of advise: don't make feature requests too soon. It can be a harsh experience to see what you probably wholeheartedly believed to be an excellent suggestion to be shot down with 20+ downvotes. Keep in mind that stack Overflow has been around since 2008, it is a very mature site (so mature it is starting to buckle under its own weight...). If a particular feature does not exist, there is probably a reason for it that has something do with the incredible size of the site's user base, or its non-forum setup. Question/discuss it first, then create the feature request.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Questions on Stack Overflow are never marked as complete. The author can select one of the answers as accepted, but that doesn't stop new answers from arriving.

We don't want to prevent people from adding new answers as technology changes constantly. New and better ways are invented to solve problems. Stack Overflow is meant to be a repository of information and this repository needs to be updated with new solutions.

If a question has been resolved in comments, it usually means that it was resolved in a way unlikely to help others, otherwise, someone would post that comment as an answer. Such questions should be closed and deleted.

Answer (score 1):

If the question was answerable by a comment then that usually means someone had the heart to point the asker in the right direction before voting to close.

I've seen answers get flogged because the answerer should have known better than to re-answer something that's been answered dozens of times.

Comments are second-class citizens and can be deleted at any time without prejudice by either the commenter or a mod.

I think you should read [Answerers who only use comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments) and particularly this answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253068/2191572