# Deleting questions or answers with many comments

Tags: discussion, comments, low-quality-posts

The decision of whether or not to "Recommend Deletion" during a review is particularly hard (for me) even for lowest-quality answers when there are many comments. Although it's clear that long discussions in comments are discouraged, the comments often contain valuable information. Often this information is provided by the asker himself, in response to the answer or to other comments. This information should *not* be lost, because then the chances are high that the same discussion will appear in a different answer.

The best thing would probably be to tell the asker to put the information from the comments into the original question, and defer the deletion of the answer, but this does not match the review workflow. Another option would be to manually extract the (presumed) "relevant" information from the comments and edit them into the question. But this would be rather subjective, invasive, and difficult, depending on how the information was provided.

So I'd like to ask: Is there a general policy or guideline how to treat answers that are delete-worthy on their own, but which contain many important and valuable comments that could help to make the original question better?

**EDIT**: The question about "[Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)" is somehow related, and the answer there is similar to the one proposed in the [answer below by Deduplicator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266056/3182664): Collect the information from the comments, and post them in a community-wiki answer. However, this is not applicable when there is not really an *answer*, but only comments that could (and should) be used to *improve* the *question* itself.

Answer (score 2):

There are some options:

- Edit it in yourself, as the poster already provided it in the comments. Beware of radical-change though.
- Provide your own answer containing all the info, giving credit where due, and recommend deletion.
- Leave a comment to the poster if there is none yet (useless they were not active fairly recently). Only do so if the comments really contain information not present on the question, other answers or their respective comments.

Now an option like "defer decision 3 weeks" would be nice. In its absence, the only fitting option is "recommend deletion", and hope for the best (i.e. someone else editing, maybe even after deletion and doing a resurrection).