# How to handle questions, which are solved via edit?

Tags: discussion, self-answer, unanswered-questions

I have seen a lot of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190404/cherry-framework-wordpress-where-are-the-shortcodes), where the asker edited his question with a remark "solved" and described the problem. I have taken a look into this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/2441442), which is for a similar problem with comments.

If I see such questions, I tend to edit the question (remove the answer), and post the answer as community wiki. Is this ok?

- It solves the problem, that there is no answer
- It does **not** solve the problem that there is no accepted answer (Should we flag this?)

Comment: I think it would be nicer to be marked as accepted, because it is implicit (The topic is handled for the asker) accepted. In the question page, all potential helpers think "there is somebody who needs help".

Comment: I'd swear this has been asked here many times before, but I'm struggling to find a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not having an answer accepted is not an actual problem.

It is Ok to post a community-wiki answer (one thing you can try first is to encourage the OP thorugh comments to move his/her answer to the answer box).

If the fix on question was just a typo in the code, then there is a close reason customized for this (problem that no longer can be reproduced):

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.