# Answer the own question with a provided comment?

Tags: discussion

As you can see on this question, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615776/prependid-false-is-ignored-in-uirepeat
, the OP answeres his own question by a comment. He pointed to the comment and that's all.

**EDIT: Apparently, the answer got deleted, by OP? Some Mod?**

Is that a normal / good / bad behaviour? And why? 
And is there any reason to downvote those answers?

Do not get me wrong, I am really glad, that answers are provided by users. But with ONLY a comment cite? Is that really necessary?

Here is the deleted answer:

[image: answer]

Here is an other example:

[JSF: Different validation message for different validator tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009797/jsf-different-validation-message-for-different-validator-tags)

The link in the comment points to the correct answer. The OP just put the link from this answer to answer his own question. This can't be serious!

Comment: Encourage them to post it as an answer.

Comment: The OP deleted it, and it had 0 votes. Added the image in

Comment: If they won't post it as an answer, you can post it in a (optionally community wiki) answer, attributing it to them.

Comment: Your second example should be closed as a duplicate, as the link in the comment actually points to an answer on another SO question, and the OP took the link from that answer and posted it as an answer. To answer your question: there is nothing wrong with the OP taking an answer given to them in the comments and posting it as an answer. If it solved their problem, it is an answer. If the commenter didn't post it as an answer, then the OP has every right to. If it's important information, it could be deleted if left in a comment. (cont.)

Comment: Though it would be seen as more polite to ask the commenter to post an answer and give them time, or at the very least make it Community Wiki, there is no rule against taking information in the comments and formulating your own answer. If it is a copy-paste of the comment, it should be attributed (which the OP of the first example clearly attempted by posting the name of the commenter) to the original commenter to be polite.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments

Comment: @Kendra As suggested by you and the other guys (specially the one, with the strange name :) ) : Can you please post your comments as an answer? Thank you, for your advices, guys!