# Answer embedded in question

Tags: discussion

It looks like the OP of this question (linked below) is trying to be helpful by posting a question and answer combo, only instead of actually adding an answer it's all embedded into the question itself. Judging by votes and the fact that I found it, it seems to be a very useful answer. I thought about editing it and moving the answer portion to where it belongs but I obviously can't post an answer in someone elses name and I think they surely deserve the points/credit.

[Bootstrap 3 jquery event for active tab change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705905/bootstrap-3-jquery-event-for-active-tab-change)

Is this worthy of a custom flag? Should I just leave it be? Is there some other course of action to take?

Comment: That is an interesting situation.  And based on the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20705905/1), the intent to post that solution was in the original post.

Comment: [Somewhat similar situataion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yep good catch. The community wiki option isn't a bad one, although if it's an active user I'd like to see them get credit for the answer. As you mentioned, the intent was clearly good.

Comment: Just ask the OP to split it into a question and an answer.

Comment: @JonasCz That was done already.

Comment: Funny thing is that without the answer, there is really not much left so it could easily have been closed and deleted already.

Comment: I hadn't noticed this discussion until @Roombatron5000 made me aware. I changed the question and added an answer. I hope the format now is more complaint. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's good of you to want to help the user gain rep from the answer, but it's unnecessary. Still, if you want to do that:

If the user is active [and Roombatron5000 says he/she is](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288443/answer-embedded-in-question?cb=1#comment167672_288443), I'd do what Gopal Aggarwal [did back in October '14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705905/bootstrap-3-jquery-event-for-active-tab-change#comment41485795_20705905) and encourage them to separate the question and answer. I'd use text something like this:

> This is great. To make it fit with SO's format, please move the part answering the question into an actual answer. After you do that, you can "accept" the answer two days later. It's perfectly acceptable here (and even encouraged) to answer your own question.

If they don't do it within a couple of days (and obviously, in this case, they haven't) and you still want to do something about it, move the answer part into a Community Wiki answer. The question will continue to gain votes and "reward" the user for posting it even though they won't gain rep from the answer — which is fine, they've had plenty of time to post the answer as an answer and you even prodded them to do it.

Standard caveat: Rep doesn't really matter, participation does. :-)

Answer (score 10):

> *" I thought about editing it and moving the answer portion to where it belongs but I obviously can't post an answer in someone elses name and I think they surely deserve the points/credit."*

You could do so, and leave your answer to the community wiki (see that checkbox appearing under your answer edit window at the right side) IMHO.
That's the most decent way without giving anyone the impression you just did it, to gain rep from that action.

---

If you edit out the solution from the question, and post it as an appropriate answer, that doesn't make the situation worse, or affecting the OP's actual reputation gain for it.

The answer will gain rep over time, and also the question will, if it's found to be useful in the future.

Comment: I think that the OP also want to give not only recognition but also any rep for that answer.  So that's a bit more challenging

Comment: @ryanyuyu If it's that popular and helpful as you assumed for that question, this (newly created) answer will certainly gain rep over time. To leave your personal credits for the OP you can upvote the question.

Comment: Yes, but community wikis don't award reputation.  It's a small but important detail.

Comment: @ryanyuyu So are you after gaining reputation, or fixing the Q&A format? The OP itself will still earn rep in future, for the question itself. That doesn't make a difference for them, compared to the situation as is.

Comment: I'm after neither.  I just wanted to point out the original "deserve the points/credit".  The community wiki only address the "credit" portion.

Comment: @ryanyuyu _"The community wiki only address the "credit" portion."_ For the proposed answer, yes. As mentioned, there's no difference for the question, as long it's edited appropriately.

Comment: Ok that's all I was curious about.  Again it is a small detail, but I just wanted to make sure there wasn't something that _perfectly_ met the OP desire.  At any rate the community wiki option is _really_ close.

Comment: Thanks. You're both absolutely right. I did of course mention the ideal solution would award the OP credit for the answer but it's a minor detail. I'll wait a day or so to give the OP a chance to edit. If nothing changes, I'll follow this suggestion.

Comment: _"You're both absolutely right."_ Oops, I'm two now again? I didn't thought I'm that drunk already this early evening :-P ...
Wait! **I am that drunk already**, since I had the impression I was discussing with the OP.

Comment: "Why the hell is this guy thanking us???"...oh wait...

Comment: @aw04 Such shit can happen, relying on drug addicts ;-) ... Coffee, ya know ;-) ...

Comment: Hey, it beats interacting with normal people

Comment: @aw04 Who ever claimed I'm _normal_. I never was after that kind of label.