# What to do with an older duplicate question that doesn't have a real answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I asked/answered [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29423337/how-do-i-change-a-sql-server-password-that-has-expired-from-c-sharp-code) a few weeks ago because I thought the question never appeared on SO anywhere.

Just now I discovered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864518/how-can-i-change-sql-server-login-account-password-on-first-login-via-c).  It doesn't have an answer (but the answer is in the comment) and is slightly different.

I don't think there's necessarily anything we *have* to do, but figured if there was some appropriate way to handle this, someone here would know.

Comment: Related to the [answer is in the comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)

Comment: Thanks @gnat. problem solved.

Comment: Interestingly, when you marked this question as a duplicate, something might have happened to gnat's auto comment from the dup flag.  So since I'm now the only other commenter, I got the notification that was meant for gnat.

Comment: @ryanyuyu new bug discovered!

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing to stop you voting to close the older question as a duplicate of the newer one. What we want is the better question with the better answer(s) to be the canonical question & answer with all other variants pointing to it.