# Asking a near-duplicate of an unanswered question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I want to ask a question that would start like this:

> I want to do X but it does not work. Here are links to some other
>   posts that are very similar, but some are unanswered and some give
>   answers that are unacceptable to me

The question would ultimately be more full-fledged than this and would include code, explanations of what I have tried, etc.

[This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253925/4103025) answer to a similar question almost addresses my question, but I think that Alexander really gets to the heart of my question when he says

> The answer says "edit your question" - do you recommend simply taking
>   it over - possibly entering specifics that may not have been
>   applicable to his situation(?), or post a bounty - which in many cases
>   isn't ideal.

I would like to provide more details for anyone that might want to help answer this question. Obviously, the details would pertain to the same problem, but would come from my own attempts to solve it. If that produces nothing I would like to offer a bounty. Essentially I want to "take over" the question, which to me suggests I should have just started my own question. It just feels wrong to intentionally ask a question I know to be basically a duplicate.

Edit: For reference,  after asking this question I decided to make [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34582637/4103025) post. Feel free to let me know if making this post was the right thing to do in my situation.

Comment: Ah, I wish that everybody considering this would think twice before actually doing it. Kudos! But @Paulie_D is right of course.

Comment: @Paulie_D I have edited my question to address your concerns.

Answer (score 2):

No...please don't. You have code.. *you do, right!?*..., post it and explain what you want and what you have tried. Posting just links, even SO links, would not be optimal IMO. Your question should stand by itself.

> Essentially I want to "take over" the [*duplicated*] question, which to me suggests I should have just started my own question. It just feels wrong to intentionally ask a question I know to be basically a duplicate.

As Servy said in: [**What to do when the question you want to ask is a duplicate?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253924/what-to-do-when-the-question-you-want-to-ask-is-a-duplicate)

> If the post has answers that are valid for that question, but that don't work for you, then the post isn't a duplicate.

So, post away...but if the answers you **do** have are unacceptable...say WHY in your question to avoid duplicate answers.

---

If your question is an *exact* duplicate of an **unanswered** question then it will either generate an answer or get none. If you get an answer we can close the old questions as duplicates of yours. Not something you need to worry about really.

See: [**What to do with an older duplicate question that doesn't have a real answer?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289925/what-to-do-with-an-older-duplicate-question-that-doesnt-have-a-real-answer?rq=1)

Comment: Correct. My post would not be a duplicate of these questions since the answer was acceptable for them, but not for me. However, as I mentioned, some questions were unanswered. These are the ones I am concerned I am duplicating. You addressed only half of my situation.

Comment: If it's not an *exact* duplicate...it's not  a duplicate really.

Comment: The question I want to ask is nearly identical to one existing question, I have just collected a bit more information about the problem. Are you saying it is okay to duplicate the question if it has no answers?

Comment: @Paulie_D Technically true, but the dupe police isn't always that perceptive. But, bytesized, if it's your concern that your question may get closed as duplicate, you should simply mention the false duplicates and explain why you ask again.

Comment: I don't see why not if you have more information,,you don't *know* that the information you now have applied to original OP's question really...unless you do. I see nothing wrong with posting a new question here, you've done the due diligence.

Comment: @GertArnold Indeed, any new question here should clarify why it should not be closed as a duplicate...at least give the dupe police a chance to think twice.

Comment: the exception is when the answer(s) to the potential duplicate(s) does not work for you **simply because you do not understand the answer**, then a duplicate is a duplicate regardless.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson We can't account for any lack of understanding. Worst case, it **is** a dupe and gets closed as such. In the scheme of things...it's not a big deal...at least the OP here is trying to do the right thing.