# Are vote viewing apps discouraged?

Tags: discussion, privileges, vote-count

I recently found that [there are apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep) that allow you to see the vote count before you get to 1k reputation. Is the use of these apps discouraged?

Comment: If it is built using the official API then they can't really discourage it because they've made the data public.

Comment: @slugster If its public data, why restrict the privilege until 1k rep?

Comment: Because it wasn't necessarily always publicly available, and because the site offers rep based incentives. If someone wants to shortcut that incentive then so be it.

Comment: Nah, you can't close it like that. Just leave it for a while, see if someone else answers. If no-one does then I'll put a proper answer in.

Comment: @jakekimds In a related question SO devs said its because the sum is denormalized and thus cheap to query, whereas the individual values are more expensive to query. But they did not say why they didn't denormalize both values.

Comment: If you find answers in comments, and nobody has expanded them to answers within a few days, Robert Harvey [suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments/251598#251598) copying them to a new community wiki post.

Comment: Are there any other privileges that grant access to things that you already have access to through apps such as this one? Not interested in circumventing it, but just curious.

Comment: @DavidB [This](http://stackapps.com/questions/2505/stack-exchange-deleted-question-viewer-broken) used to work on most questions but it is now broken.

Comment: @jakekimds That's cool. I find it intriguing that StackExchange does not care when users do it.

Comment: @DavidB The last one I posted in the comments was a 'hack' exploiting a bug.

Comment: @jakekimds Oh, that's cool.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's not a problem at all. The vote splits are not classified information: besides the API, they can be obtained from the Data Explorer, or by opening the timeline page `/posts/{question-id}/timeline`. The 1K privilege amounts merely to making it available through the site  interface, without you having to work to get it.

Comment: @jakekimds it is limited to a privilege to rate limit (as the database query is a little more expensive). Using an app still requires you to have made a conscious decision to install it so naturally the number of people with 'access' is still limited.

Comment: The timeline feature is especially good. Shows when what happened.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's a database thing? I always thought it was a psychological thing. Hmm.

Comment: Woah, that timeline page is great! How did I never find out about this before? Have an upvote.

Comment: Since some commenters like Timeline, here's a link to a [bookmarklet](http://dropproxy.com/f/7FC#timeline) to have it shown for the currently open question.