# Will this upvoted question be closed as Off Topic?

Tags: discussion

so, I was reviewing Triage in my never ending quest to get a Gold Badge, and one of the questions for Review was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649071/unable-to-set-env-vairables-using-runtime-exec/v-vairables-using-runtime-exec/)

In order to help, I commented and defined it in review as *needs improvement*

Then another user gave a simple answer after noticing a Typo on the question, which would have caused the problem. The answer seemed to me to be *Not an answer*, more like a comment, so I added a comment under the answer that it should be a comment.

The response came back that the OP was satisfied with the suggestion, and indeed the OP marked that answer as the answer.

Now for me this question should be closed as Off-Topic, as it is caused by a simple typo error, **and** the answer should be flagged as **NOT AN ANSWER**

or am I being too tyrannical here - especially as it has now gotten another answer for a high rep user?

I have flagged the question for closure, and am asking for advise from the community about whether to flag the answer as well.

Comment: Well the answer is an answer. IMO just closing the question is enough.

Comment: I just think it should have been posted as a comment

Comment: **Don't put answers in comments** If the question was based around a typo, fine, close it, but the answer *is still an answer*.

Comment: @OurManInBananas yeah if it's just a comment then we have another [question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)

Comment: This isn't about being tyrannical. This is about being logical. What would an answer be if not an answer?

Comment: The answer is correct, however little text there is, it is an answer and is factually correct. What could the question be closed as? It's localised, but a user asked a valid question with a valid problem, and received a valid answer. Albeit low quality all round and basic coding diagnosis by the Q OP would have saved asking in the first place. I don't see anything wrong in terms of the site rules/requirements though.

Comment: @James There's a close reason for typos, which the question in question is: _"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."_

Comment: @James: On SO we expect questions to have some lasting value - questions that turn out to be based on one-off typos don't help anyone but the OP at that very point in time; keeping them around serves little to no benefit, and might even be embarrassing to the OP.

Comment: I have flagged it for close under the *what Kendra said*

Comment: @BoltClock I agree with that, but was not aware a close reason existed for "typographical error". Makes sense, and glad it does exist really. Cheers.

Comment: @James: well it's under *Off topic*

Comment: @OurManInBananas I know now, I'm no noob to Stack Exchange, I just never read *that part* of the "no longer repro" close reason :)

Comment: @Bolt - couldn't agree more.  Now how are we actually going to get rid of it?   The odds that two days from now, anybody with sufficient rep is going back to post a delete vote are very low.  You can help.