# Can we have the ability to hit return in comments without it posting the comment?

Tags: feature-request, comments

When commenting on questions the text or code is squashed together. Similar to peas in a cramped pod. We can't hit return to start a new paragraph. I had an example today where someone answered my question. I replied saying the suggested answer did not fully work. they replied back, then I needed to reply with a snippet of code but it was unreadable in the comments as it had spaces/paragraphs removed. I'm always hitting return to start a new paragraph and viola, my comment is posted.

Comment: Comments can't have multiple paragraphs or newlines, so inserting one would be useless anyway. You can use Shift + Enter if you'd like, but it won't display in the rendered comment.

Comment: Downvoting feature requests on Meta indicates people do not agree with the feature request. There's nothing being taken personally. Comments are not meant for long discussions, code blocks, or conversations, and there is simply no need to have returns in them. If you have so much to say that you need paragraphs, write an answer.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​If the code snippet is relevant to your question, then why not just update your question to include it? If it's not, what's the point of sharing it in the first place?

Comment: Since you're worried about the downvotes here, you must not realize that they don't affect you one bit...except maybe your mental state. You don't lose any imaginary points like on the main site. Also, there's no reason to give up on meta just because people seem to disagree with one suggestion (though that's your right if you wish). A lot of people have made suggestions they thought were good that were shot down by the majority and others are still waiting on things to be implemented. Let it go

Comment: To me what's a pain is not that the breaks don't render but the fact that if you make a mistake and hit enter the comment field closes. Usually right in the middle of typing something. So it's disruptive. But I guess it's convenient for some.

Comment: I just want to say thanks, jeez!

Comment: @codemagic before this post I had 6 rep, now I have 2, I cant even answer on here now. Some one has been through and downvoted 1 question I had from 8 months ago. It hasn't been viewed for months and suddenly as soon as I post an idea my rep disappears, that is no good.

Comment: (1) Don't edit your questions to ask something entirely different. (2) Voilà not Viola.

Comment: @ Martin smith, the reason for the silly edit was. I'm dissapinted and annoyed for this reason: 
``
``  
before this post I had 6 rep, now I have 2, I cant even answer on here now. Some one has been through and downvoted 1 question I had from 8 months ago. It hasn't been viewed for months and suddenly as soon as I post an idea my rep disappears, that is no good.

Comment: So your rep decreased by -4. Post a single good answer that even gets a single upvote and you will more than recover that.

Comment: @martin smith it should not have happened. I know that would fix it but now I cant even answer on here. Posting an idea should not decrease my rep. I'm a newbie that took me months to get. I was averaging 1 point a month. All that work just gone in an instant. This needs looking into.

Comment: No offence but I don't really see much work there. You asked two questions and posted a single self answer.

Comment: I have spent hours going through questions trying to research an answer just for rep but I am too inexperienced. Its 6 point worth of work regardless of how much work has gone into it and it should not have been taken away.

Comment: You do realise these are fake internet points, not redeemable for anything?

Comment: without the points I can't have privileges on this site. Privileges will help me make progress.

Comment: *if you make a mistake and hit enter the comment field closes. Usually right in the middle of typing something.* - @Elin - I get that but if you remove hitting enter to post the comment you'll get people complaining about having to either take their hands off the keyboard to post a comment or having to tab over to it, especially since most comment systems don't work that way.

Comment: @monkhouse instead of whining about it, earn the privileges!

Comment: @monkhouse the privileges only go part of the way -  the most important aspect of your involvement that will allow you to 'make progress' is the contribution of good content.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only place I've ever needed something like this is when I want to provide some code or a small example in response to a question. For instance, I might comment:

> Your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, and `SqlDataReader` all need to be in `using` blocks.

Now, that's enough for someone who knows what a `using` block is. To someone new to `using` blocks, I would actually like to give a tiny example:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("xxx")){
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ...", conn){
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()){
            while (reader.Read()) { /* ... */ }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, since I can't do that in a comment, if it comes to it, I will create a CW (Community Wiki) answer. In this case, it's basically a formatted comment.

Note that's in the case where the lack of `using` blocks isn't the cause of the problem. In that case, I'm willing to take credit for solving the problem.

Now, I'm willing to admit that this is me being too lazy to create a little blog post I can direct them to, or even a small canonical self-answered question. If I were a better person, I'd do one of those two things.

But not today.

Comment: [gist.github.com](//gist.github.com/) is wonderful for posting small example snippets for reference, and when you clean up your comments after the question has been solved you can delete the gist. As a rule comments are assumed to be transient, so any relevant information should be included in the question or answer itself. This feature request would promote [answering questions in the comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) which would be a bad thing.

Comment: @TinyGiant: yeah, that's why I downvoted the question. I expect downvotes on my answer as well. It's meant to be, "this is the best reason I've found for fancy comments, and it's not actually good enough to change comments, so let's not do that".

Comment: just to donate is all I wanted.

Answer (score 9):

Comments aren't for extended explanations (which a paragraph implies). From the [help page about comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

> #### When should I comment?
>
> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request **clarification** from the author;
> - Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but **minor or transient information** to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

If you have to provide code to answer clarification to your question, that is what the **edit** button is for. Provide more information in the question itself where you can utilize the full editor. Comments can (and are) removed frequently. Important information that is relevant to getting your question answered belongs in the question itself, not buried in the comments.

Answer (score 5):

A WIP section implies that your question isn't complete.  Incomplete questions are usually [met with closure](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) until they get back into shape.  It's a *form* of WIP, but it's not a very pleasant one.

I would strongly encourage that you don't post questions where you feel like you have to go back and forth.  If you do have to ask for more help or for more clarification, add the details to the **existing question** that you have and direct any answerers to the new portion in your question.  (Don't use this as an opportunity to ask a new question, as that's frowned  upon.)