# Show Comment Count when No Answers?

Tags: feature-request, questions, comments

Related to: [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)

Right no way to see that anyone other than the asker has written anything unless it was written as an answer. You can see that its been voted on and that people have viewed it, but you can't see that anyone actually wrote anything unless you click on it.

This means that you're potentially passing over a question with useful comments, because you don't realize that the comments are there.

My proposal is that anytime a question has no answers, it should instead show the comment count (perhaps in a faded gray or smaller font to emphasis that it's showing the comment count, not the answer count.)

This is not a duplicate of the one that was marked. The other one has a misleading title, so I changed the title of the other one.

Comment: Just say **No** to more faded colors and smaller fonts.

Comment: @rene Maybe I misunderstood that one, but it seemed to be all about having ajax methods that would automatically refresh comments or something. Yes, the title of it certainly makes it look like a duplicate, but it is not. That other one should probably have its title changed.

Comment: It might just be me, but I think a comment counter would be neat to have. Just to see it. Plus i doubt it would be much work to implement?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you deciding to view and potentially answer a question based on if it has comments or not? You should either be able to answer a question without the need of comments from the OP or other users or be willing to take the time to create the comments yourself asking for clarification that is needed. Either way the fact that comments are there or not shouldn't matter in deciding to click on a question link to possibly answer it.

Showing if a question has answers and or an accepted answer on the other hand is very useful as it lets a user who is looking for answers have a quick check to see if there might be useful information there. For a question with no answers however having or not having a comment does not change the quality of the question as there is no difference if someone comments and nothing has been changed or if no one has commented.

Comment: This is intended to be more useful for the scenario when looking at questions where potentially you can find help than in the scenario where you're looking at questions to help on. Although in the scenario deciding whether to go into a question to help on or not, I can imagine looking at the title/tags and thinking "I should go in and comment on the title/tags to help this person make the question jump out at someone who knows the answer" - if I already see comments, it indicates it has already gotten the attention of someone else who can help with that kind of thing.

Comment: How would that help at all when a comment is likely to be someone asking for the OP to clarify what they are asking or to provide a code sample. The fact that a comment is there doesn't mean that there is any information about solving the problem and is more likely to mean that there are unanswered questions that the OP needs to solve.

Answer (score 1):

> you're potentially passing over a question with useful comments,
>   because you don't realize that the comments are there.

And quoting your comment to JoeW's answer:

> if I already see comments, it indicates it has already gotten the
>   attention of someone else who can help with that kind of thing

We cannot possibly know that from a numerical comment count.

I pondered over this some time ago (I think when I was relatively new to the site).
However, *there being* comments is no indication that those comments are... anything at all.

The comments could be everything required - asking for more code, etc.
Or, they could be about "Don't use `mysql_`", or useless rants about nothing.

One has to peer in to find out if the comments are of any use. There could be 6 comments in there and you come along with your previous knowledge/experience and add that one comment which prompts the OP to edit and add the details required to be able to answer.

Also, having upvotes on comments can potentially generate credibility.

So always viewing an unanswered question with comments means you can either, upvote crucial comments, or add one which is needed.
So, either way, you're needed in there even if *it already has X comments* :)

---

I'd go as far as saying the same applies to us seeing an answer count, and even an accepted answer!
The accepted answer might be ok for the OP, but we are striving for providing professional advice, and not just for OPs.

So the accepted answer may well be "ok" for the OP, but you could add another answer which has better info, or maybe a more professional way of doing things, with better code examples or a much better approach.
The OP and others viewing the question will never obtain this better info if we all just see X answers or 1 accepted answer and move along.

If answers can be like this, then knowing if a question has comments or not is entirely useless.

Comment: The sort of thing that I was referring to is the kind of things you might comment on: formatting your post/code, picking tags, picking a title. If there are no comments, then I know that nobody has left that sort of advice. If there are comments, then someone else is already tending to the question and the asker while they wait for someone to answer it.

Comment: "*If there are comments, then someone else is already tending to the question and the asker while they wait for someone to answer it*" Say the site implements your request - you are viewing the questions page listing and see a question has 10 comments - are those comments useful, or useless? You do not know until you go into the question and look, so a comment count is pointless :)

Comment: It's not pointless. It tells me someone is already offering some feedback and help. Whether that feedback/help is useful or not isn't actually known, but if I have the option of looking at something with 0 comments or 10 comments (or even just 1), I'll check out the one with 0 comments. Views offer a somewhat similar metric, but you don't know whether the people viewing are actually people who will make any effort to help.