# How to improve a low quality question, with no answer, where the OP answered in comment

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, self-answer, quality-improvement

I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31292234/c-sharp-html-create-download-link) today and tried to improve it by asking clarifying questions, but eventually just flagged it as unclear. **What other actions can I take to improve it?**

Here is the question:

> C# & HTML create download link
>
> I created a TCP web site by parsing HTML(windows form).All good until
>   I tried to create a download link for a file located on my desktop.I
>   used tag first from a notepad and start as a website and it works and
>   when I tried to run from my program it doesn't. I catch that is a
>   resource problem so my ask is how can create a download link?How is
>   the procedure?I set wrong the resource source?

**This question**

1. **is low quality**
2. **has no answer**
3. **has the OP answering own question in
   the comments**

As an SO member trying to do his civic duty, what should I do in this case? I am not really willing to spend time to try and edit it further and without any code, It will be hard to make this a quality question or give it a quality answer. I'm also unwilling to ask the OP for clarifying questions as it seemed the OP answered own question in the comments.

What is an appropriate response?

I flagged it for closure as "unclear", but I'm not certain that it is. Should I try and edit the question then post the OP's answer as a wiki as described in this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)?

Comment: For the record, there are already 3 close votes on the post for "unclear".

Comment: I guess I would see that with 250 rep and that might have satisfied me enough to probably not ask this one. :)

Comment: Ask about it on Meta and let the effect deal with it?

Comment: You can't see close votes until you hit 3k. The 250 rep give you the ability to see close votes on your _own_ posts. If you like, hop into a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and someone can give you a quick answer.

Comment: @Will, that's exactly what I did

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The post has been closed as "unclear". There were 3 close votes by the time this meta question was created, so that close reason was set in stone.

Because of this comment by the OP:

> Yep but I succeed to manage it works by sending to the stream between the server and the client the byte array of the file on the link open by `<a href="/link" download>` extension.Thank you anyway - [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31292234/c-sharp-html-create-download-link#comment50581130_31292234)

it could have been also closed as "off-topic > a problem that can no longer be reproduced".

As for what you did, I think it was appropriate. There are 4 main things you can do to help a bad post:

1. Downvote - send a signal that the post needs help
2. Flag/Vote to close - stop answers from being added until the post is improved
3. Edit - modify the content of the post to make it more clear
4. Comment - ask the OP questions to clear up issues in the post

You did #2 and 4 (maybe #1 as well). I think you did your job.

I would have gone ahead and fixed the grammar issues in the post - trying to make coherent sentences from what has been written. No, you won't be able to fix *all* the issues (like the missing code), but the "readability" portion will be majorly improved.

However, this comment by another user

> This question is garbled stream of consciousness, no one will ever be able to answer you. Spending time framing your question and rewrite, make it easy to understand.

While funny for any other member of the community, could be phrased *a bit* nicer.

Comment: readers of your answer may think that ["garbled stream of consciousness..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31292234/c-sharp-html-create-download-link#comment50576395_31292234) comment was posted by asker of this meta question, but as far as I can tell, it was posted by another user

Comment: "*This question is garbled stream of consciousness*" That is still making me laugh