# Should I answer my own question?

Tags: discussion, questions

So, I made [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740309/how-should-i-notify-a-changed-setting-across-projects-inside-a-solution) question some time ago. It was one of my first questions, and I got it solved out, but the answer to the problem was in the comments section.

I find it unfair to answer it Myself, and the users that helped me get nothing from it.

(I know that some other devs from my company have also benefited from the question, and it's kinda of a Newbie answer, so it could help some other folks. So, I do not want to delete it, even if it's kinda mediocre.)

Should I answer it myself? Is it not unfair to those who helped me with that problem in particular?

Comment: By unfair - I mean: Those who answered it in the comments will get no reputation from it, right?

Comment: I tend to post another comment (directed at them) that asks whether they would like to elaborate on the comments and post them as an answer, so that I can accept it. Might be an option before writing your own one.

Comment: If they haven't answered in over a year then go ahead and make the answer and cite the comments/users who helped.

Comment: @anderas I did this already :(

Comment: @Malavos then do what codeMagic suggests! (After this, my comment looks kind of ironic/meta ;-) )

Comment: I would comment and ask them to write what they posted as an answer (if it hasn't been too incredibly long/they're still active. The question you link looks a bit old, so this may not work.) If they don't answer respond within a reasonable time, you can write your own answer. You can attribute it to them with a link to the comments that helped you, and if you wish not to gain rep from it, you can check the "community wiki" box under the answer text field.

Comment: @codeMagic thanks for that, Community wiki could solve it. But I'm in doubt if this is fair to the people who answered it, still. See this answer here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251600/2890522 isn't something like this possible in this case?

Comment: No, writing an answer on another user's behalf isn't possible, not even for mods. The best you can do is community wiki the answer if you really feel like you shouldn't get the rep for it. It's completely fair for you to write an answer to your own question and attribute it to the user(s) that helped in the comments, _especially_ after this long. If they wanted the rep from it, they could have posted an answer in the time since they posted the comments.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about fair. It's been over a year and the commentors aren't worried. Link to the comments/users in your answer and that is fair enough. People who are good for the site won't care that they didn't get rep. I answer in comments often and someone else makes it an answer and gets the rep. It doesn't matter. If I cared enough about that, I would have answered. And, no that is currently not possible but not a bad feature request

Comment: Alright, @Kendra (and hello again), codeMagic, thanks for the help. I'll be sure to answer it as community Wiki and attribute the users on the answer. Thanks!

Comment: It's more fair to other users with a similar problem to post an answer then for them to go through the comments. And we aren't here to build rep, that's a side effect.

Comment: Kendra, codeMagic, could you post that as an aswer? lel

Comment: Also, what to do with this question here? There the other one pointed as a duplicate, which is kinda not like my problem - I was aiming for a solution that's fair... Comunity wiki seems nice, because I won't get rep

Comment: What's different about it? The top answer on that dupe says CW. And it's by a mod, if that makes any difference to you. I'm really confused on why no one else has voted as the same so far

Comment: @codeMagic because I was aiming to the most fair solution, but I guess you're right, if the most fair is CW, and the top is CW... this solves it :). I marked it as duplicate.