# What can another user do when questions are answered in the comments and neither questioner or answerer have posted it as an answer?

Tags: discussion

I have already seen this thread : (so, don't quote it in your answer).

[Mark a comment as answer to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question)

My question is : As a well-meaning volunteer, who wants to keep questions statuses accurate, what can I do ? 
X has asked a question, 
Y answered it in the comments, 
X acknowledges in the comments that the answer is valid.

Say, I have contacted Y to post it as an answer, no response. 
Say, I have contacted X to quote Y's comment and post an answer to his own question, no response.

Can I , as a reader, quote the comment and post an answer, so that question status is tied up as "answered" ? Or would it be viewed as some immoral snatch of attention/points due to someone else ?

The link that I referred to, above, does discuss some related issues, but the accepted answer does not provide any guideline about how a third volunteer should react when he spots such questions. It would be best if SO provided a clear guideline about what a well-meaning, discerning volunteer user can do when he spots questions answered in the comments.

With a process flow, this may convert to a feature request such as the one below. But that is not what I seek mainly. I am not looking for a feature, as much as I am looking for what I can do as a volunteer.

Feature: Review volunteer proposes that comment may be accepted as an answer. If other reviewers agree and notice clear evidence of questioner acknowledging the answer as valid, in the thread, Questioner and Answerer are both notified by SO to take action. If there is no action taken by either, SO marks the question as answered, saying "A answered the question in the comments, proposed as an answer by Joe" and so on. The question doesn't appear in unanswered questions any more.

Comment: Just post the comment as an answer, explaining as much as you can. Make sure to provide attribution. Mark it as Community Wiki, or not. If it gets an upvote it will remove the question from the unanswered list.

Comment: Do you have some examples?

Comment: *"I have already seen this thread : (so, don't quote it in your answer)."*  When asking for help and/or guidance, consider *not* starting off with a command.

Comment: I frequently review unanswered questions, some upvoted well, in my tagged topics. 
For example : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862472/sql-server-2008-transactional-replication-missing-end-comment-mark
Martin's comment (also, the most upvoted comment) is acknowledged soon after by Loic as the answer.

Comment: Yeah, this comes up a lot. For instance, see [this other meta question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)

Comment: @PaulRoub : Noted. May be I should have said : :" Please... " . Would that have been okay ? Or did you mean, I shouldn't preclude possible comments ?

Comment: "NOTE: I've already read ..., but it doesn't fully answer my question because..." is generally more-productive. You actually described those reasons later in your post, so everything an answerer *needs* to know is in place. I'd just leave out the "don't do this!" part, however nicely phrased.

Comment: Okay, Paul Roub. 
@Kendra : Haa, good link. Has a clear guideline. Dunno how I missed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the answer from the comments and post it as an answer, but please, use either clear attribution or, even better, mark the answer as community wiki content. You will not get reputation for the community wiki content.

Comment: Thats okay, I am not looking for reputation. Will try the community wiki route.

Comment: When you submit something as community wiki and use proper attribution, its absolutely acceptable and even very desireable to formulate a correct answer from a comment into an actual answer.

Comment: Is duplicate topics in community wiki considered okay ? ( Just in case, what I am converting into a wiki , already has a wiki to it ? )

Comment: You don't *either* use attribution *or* use CW.  You *always* need to attribute the content, since it is not your own, and you can optionally use CW or not; that's simply a convention and not a requirement.

Comment: @WhirlMind If there's a duplicate post then just vote to close as a duplicate; don't post an answer.

Comment: @WhirlMind CW is just mark on post that essentially used as "I'm not an author of the post" (no rep). Note that there is a difference between simply converting comment into answer (CW is strongly  recommended) vs. providing significantly expanded answer approximately based on comment - where you are welcome to post as regular answer (attribution requires for both cases).