# What to do with questions which are asked foolishly

Tags: discussion, questions, help-improvement

If someone has asked a question foolishly and then given a reason for it no longer being a problem (in a comment), for examples:

- Issue was that/ this I solved it.
- That was my server issue, it's working now.
- I wasn't aware of setting and now it's working.

I think that's not a valid answer and it's waste our time as well.

I tried to solve various question and found out question was just waste of time like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918260/open-cart-fatal-error-class-controllermodule-not-found)

I know many questions and comments can be useful like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683191/opencart-2-0-3-1-contact-form-not-validating) but what about the first type of question/person?

I check [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) but it's not correct because if the answer is not valid then what to do with these types of questions?

Comment: I tend to close vote - typographical error, can no longer be reproduced.

Comment: Getting such a question closed is very hard, it takes another 4 SO users and pretty unlikely that enough of them still show up.  Zero odds with a [tag] like that.  So only really effective thing you can do is DV the question with the hope that it encourages the OP to delete the question.  And if not then it ought to eventually be deleted by the machine.

Comment: @HansPassant True, although the cases I've seen tend to be self-answered by the OP that gets pity upvotes :/

Comment: Happy to say the question is now closed. =D I usually try to closevote those questions too for the typo reason, though it's tough when they have such low-traffic tags...

Comment: I think it's worth clarifying that the "typo reason", isn't just for typos - it also includes "can no longer be reproduced", but it also fits for questions where it can easily be reproduced, just by undoing whatever thing turned out to be the problem for the simple reason it contains this sentence: _"this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."_

Comment: @JamesThorpe which is something most voters don't know... also, it can be used for stuff that is impossible to figure out what the problem is/was yet somehow got solved (or not). The objetive is that the next user that has the same problem don't find DenverCoder9 post.

Comment: More directly...diplomatically explain to the questioner that their answer will not help future viewers and ask them to delete their question. This will re-engage the questioner in a non-negative way. Also vote to close their question to get that process under way.

Comment: I do what @markE describes - I downvote, vote to close, and explicitly ask the OP to delete. Sometimes I've done the opposite: the OP closed after solving, but I thought it was actually an interesting situation, and I voted to reopen, and got hold the OP and asked him to reopen and post his solution, and he did and I upvoted both the question and the answer.

Comment: Please note that these questions aren't necessarily bad - sometimes someone might have the same setting or other general situation that will make him encounter such an error. When it's a typo then obviously it's probably not useful, but  some situations might look "not reproducible", but if someone encountered it, then it's likely someone else will.

Comment: Haven't all of us posted a foolish question at least one time?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As [Gimby](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/424903/gimby) already says in a comment, such questions should be closed as “off-topic” with the following reason.

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

If you don't have enough reputation to close-vote yet, you may instead flag the question if you feel it really should be closed.

Since such questions most likely “do not show any research effort, are unclear or not useful”, down-voting might also be appropriate.

Finally, more than once, leaving a comment asking the OP to voluntarily remove their question as no answer is sought any more has worked for me. Especially if the question has negative votes on it, many people will be willing to remove it on their own but of course, they don't have to so you shouldn't do more than asking politely. I have used a comment like this one for this purpose.

> If you think that your solution might help other people, please consider posting it as an answer ([you can answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)). Otherwise, I think this question should be closed as it won't be helpful to other people. You can delete your question yourself, if you want.

Before suggesting voluntarily deletion, be sure to check that the OP can actually delete the post. They can't do so if there is an up-voted answer, an accepted answer or there are multiple answers (even if there are no up-votes).  See [*How does deleting work?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that), assuming that that reference is kept up-to-date.

Comment: *Don't suggest voluntarily deletion if there is at least one up-voted answer because the OP won't be able to do so in this case.*. Isn't it enough to just have an answer (not upvoted) for the OP not being able to close?

Comment: @WoJ [How does deleting work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that). Needs either: a) an upvoted answer, or b) accepted answer, or c)multiple answers (even without upvotes) in order to be unable to delete his own question.

Comment: @Fermiparadox Good point, I have updated the answer.