# What to do when asker offers free rep points?

Tags: discussion, reputation

So there's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36775959/osmdroid-error-no-suitable-constructor-found-for-overlayno-arguments-constr) question I came by today with the OP asking a question and then solving it himself in an edit.

However at the end of his edit he says...

> those bonus points are still out there for the taking, friends - i will UPVOTE AND APPROVE the first answer posted

I don't know how I feel about this, is this something acceptable? I feel bad copying an answer and making it my own, I feel those are "dirty points" I shouldn't be taking.

What should SO users do in such situation?

EDIT: After several reflections, I have realised that it was not the OP real intention, but a miscommunication from him. See [@albciff's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323413/6263209) answer.

Comment: In cases where the OP is no longer active I sometimes post an answer as community wiki. That creates the Q/A pair, voting can happen but I won't have the rep from it.

Comment: @rene is correct, and I did exactly that now. (before seeing the comment.)

Comment: You did your magic @ShadowWizard ... again ?????

Comment: @rene again? hmm... now you make me feel like I forget something. :]

Comment: Very related: [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)

Comment: No clue why is almost everyone so much against it, if this is wrong then what about a **Bounty**?

Comment: @HankyPanky There is a difference between a bounty and the situation we had. A bounty is when someone offers rep points to the first person who finds a working answer, here the asker found the answer by himself, but he still had the opportunity to award points if someone else would have posted is answer, so he offered the opportunity to earn points by suggesting someone to copy/paste is answer. However, in the end, it wasn't is true intention, just a miscommunication.

Comment: So even if the real intention was to award points to someone else who went ahead and posted that solution as an answer what's wrong with that? Bounty is not really for working answers only. Even if there are answers on your question but you dont really like them you can start a bounty hoping for even better answers

Comment: Read valid reasons to award bounty here http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/  there is no mention of 'first working answer'

Comment: @HankyPanky Okay, my bad, I wrote a reply too fast without proofreading myself. Anyways this is off-topic, the real problem here was the OP was encouraging users to steal credit by answering with a solution that wasn't there own.

Comment: "What to do when asker offers free rep points?" Take them if you need them, otherwise ignore the offer.

Comment: @Trilarion: As curators of this community, we have a higher obligation than just "ignoring" behaviours about which we are unsure.

Comment: as author of offer and phrase, i inform that ALBCIFF's interpretation is spot on.  as he well remarked, i may had applied non-native-anglo language structures to my phrasing.

Answer (score 103):

I think that something is misundertood here. The complete phrase from the question was really (check the [question edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36775959/revisions) ):

> Tks to Spy and MKer who commented instead of answering (those bonus points are still out there for the taking, friends -  i will UPVOTE AND APPROVE the first answer posted).

Then IMO the OP is not offering 'free' points for anyone, he wants to give the opportunity to @spy and @mker users who pointed out the solution through the comments.

This way I think is not unfair since it seems that these users really found the answer.

Remark, in general this behaviour is not acceptable but for me this is a different case.

Comment: You brought an interesting point of view on the situation, funny no one saw it that way. If this was in fact the OP original intention, then we have a miscommunication here caused by: 1) A phrase miss-worded. 2) The fact that he didn't comment to bring it to MKer and Spy's attention. 3) An unusual behaviour towards rep points.

Comment: @M.Haché 1): it's a not native english speaker point of view for a phrase miss-wordered `:)`. 2) and 3): Totally agree with you.

Comment: Hahaha, proves us how syntax is important. I won't make this the accepted answer because it doesn't really answer the original question but I will mention it in an edit to prevent people from falsely incriminating him. I just saw that people went downvoting him so I feel bad now. :/

Comment: In most cases, @M.Haché it can be customary for someone to post the answer, but as a Community Wiki - such that no advantages can effectively be earned from the answer to the user who posted it.

Comment: "give credit to where it is due" As the author of the original offer, @albciff THIS IS THE CORRECT EXPLANATION.  It resulted in the awarding of bonus points to the person who effectively solved the problem.  BUT, if someone HAD come along and copied their text and posted as answer, this 3rd person would have been awarded the bonus points IF `mker` and `spy` had not posted anything.

Comment: @albciff, you also recognized and iberian thought pattern.  hooray for you.

Comment: @tonygil my problem is that I don't speak english... I translate my spanish/catalan thoughts literally... the lost to the river :P

Comment: This puts a whole different view on the matter. I think the misleading bit is actually the title of this meta post, we all viewed the question with a default mindset of the OP trying to give away rep points. That being said the question has still generated a good discussion around the topic so it's served it's purpose.

Answer (score 19):

You already did what should be done. Suggest in a comment to the OP that instead of posting the solution in an edit they answer their own question.

There isn't really much more you can do, and I would not suggest engaging further with the OP or manually editing their post to remove the content while placing it in an answer.

Perhaps in the future if you encounter this you can point users to this https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer to inform them that there is nothing wrong with answering their own question.

Comment: *I would not suggest engaging further with the OP or manually editing their post to remove the content while placing it in an answer.* Not even in a community wiki?

Comment: @BSMP - I feel like given time the OP will place the content in an answer. And if not, over time the post will probably languish and be removed automatically. The main issue with placing this in an answer (wiki or not) is that it is just duplicate content from what already exists in the question, and more often than not removing that content from a post in an edit causes conflict. If users were a little more thick skinned it would be nice to simply edit the question into shape by removing the excess and then post it as an answer, but it could backfire easily.

Comment: _and I would not suggest engaging further with the OP or manually editing their post_ this reads as if you **wouldn't** suggest editing the post, which I don't think is what you meant - although it may just be me that read it like that...

Comment: Stack Overflow is about contents, not people. **it does not matter who post that content**, so it's totally fine, IMO, to post such an answer, using CW to avoid getting reputation you don't really deserve.

Comment: Again, as a group this may work (as can be seen with Shadow Wizard's edit), especially when done by a high rep user with a discussion from meta to back it. But as a single user, doing this may cause strife. Your mileage may very. I still would not suggest doing this at large. Often questions where this occurs aren't very high quality and the return on time invested is very low.

Comment: Or point them to http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer instead of that MSE FAQ entry

Comment: @Bergi - Good point

Comment: i wasnt answering my own question, i was asking someone to promote a comment to answer because, as such, i could reward him/her with the deservèd bonus points.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is absolutely **not** acceptable.

Votes are there for a reason, they help good and useful information stay at the top of the page where it ought to be for any future users with the same problem.

If the answer posted was genuinely a good answer, and *actually* solved the problem in the question - then that is valid, although users shouldn't advertise 'free' rep points for the fun of it as this detracts from the whole point of community moderation.

> What should SO users do in such situation?

Edit it out (which I've now done) as it's not actually relevant to the question or problem, ignore it and only post answers that provide meaningful information.

**Reputation comes with being a valuable part of the SO community, having a high rep and being of no use serves no purpose to anyone**

Comment: Editing out without posting it again as answer does more harm than good. (The solution is just lost)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I actually meant just editing out the 'free rep' offer which is [what I did](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36775959/5) but overlooked the fact that the answer was still in the question section - Travis took care of that though pretty much straight away.

Comment: @MacroMan - To be fair, Shadow edited both the question into shape and placed the wiki answer. I just made a small edit the answer to make it sound less like an edit section and more like a solution.

Comment: @TravisJ you're absolutely right, my eyes deceiveth me. Maybe it's time to actually go to sleep for a bit....

Comment: WHOOOAAAA!  hold your horses, hotshot.  as author of said offer, i was asking someone to promote what they had posted as a comment to answer, because it had worked for me, OP, and solved my problem.  I never offered undeserved points to anyone.

Comment: @tonygil see my comment on top answer

Comment: "who's the hotshot now?" MY APOLOGIES @MacroMan - as a partial justification, S.O. is not the ideal platform for following the chronology of multiple input entry points by same user.