# User A gives correct answer in comments / User B posts the answer later

Tags: discussion

This is the post with my question:

[Overwriting ViewRenderer in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37679623/overwriting-viewrenderer-in-xamarin)

"Dylan S" answered in the comments. Then "jzeferino" posted a comment.

So while the second person to answer does not "deserve" the points, if a reader comes later he/she would like to see an accepted answer.

I've searched about the issue and the only meta discussion I've found is about "how to deal with answers that are posted as a comment":

[Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)

Comment: The second person deserves the points. If the commenter doesn't want to post an answer, it's their loss.