# Answer "stolen" from comments after a long period of time

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

[I'm not sure how to react to answer posted to the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34158507/module-comctl32-ocx-failed-to-load-in-windows-10-home)

It's an old question, but just popped up in the review queue due to a new answer. But the answer was already done by someone in the comments about 5 months ago. They've taken the answer from the comments, added a Microsoft article and posted it. How do people feel about this? I feel it's bad etiquette of someone trying to steal and answer, however it was never officially answered.

Comment: He forgot to flag the comment as "Obsolete" so it could be deleted.  You can do it yourself, problem solved.

Comment: If the commenter wanted the rep they should have posted an answer. As it is the answer provides more than the comment.

Comment: Wasn't sure on protocol here, thanks for clearing that up @HansPassant

Comment: I don't feel the answer does provide much more @RobertLongson, reading the Microsoft Article doesn't provide much information on the error, just stating the file is in the wrong place, which the comment already covered

Comment: Hans doesn't seem to mind too much and he wrote the comment!

Comment: It's perfectly okay to "steal" an answer that is posted as a comment.

Comment: [This appears to be a linked discussion which is quite interesting on the subject](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)

Comment: The text in the comment box before you start typing is: "Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information. Avoid answering questions in comments."

Comment: It doesn't bother me about the downvotes @CodeCaster, that's life. Still, I got my question answered and promoted some interesting discussion. That was my goal :)

Answer (score 3):

According to the link already pointed to in comments the best way to go about this is to take the comment, post it as an answer and check the community wiki.

[Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)

Even though there doesn't seem to have any rule saying you must check the community wiki if you do so.

I did, but I don't really know if this checkbox is really made just for this.