# Flagging an answer as a copy of a comment of another person

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, disputed-flags, moderators

A person who answered a question just copied a comment of another person below the question, and wrote it as an answer. Should it be flagged?

Comment: Is there a link to that answer?

Comment: I would like to share a link, but I think it would be kind of rude, because I am not sure about it.

Comment: In my opinion there's nothing wrong with that as long as the credit is given to the one who commented. An answer has more visibility than a comment, so if it actually answers the question it may even be a good practice. After a few minutes/hours though, not 10seconds after the comment popped.

Comment: @TimF no, there is no credit given to the one who commented. And the answer was published 21 hours later than the comment was published.

Answer (score 5):

## No

If a user just provides a comment without bothering to answer then **there is no answer** and Stack Overflow is about Questions and Answers.

Comments are ephemeral by design and may be deleted at any point.

Providing an *actual* answer using the comment as a basis is acceptable BUT you should include the origin of the answer by way of attribution.

See Also: [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)

Edit:

Thanks to @rene for pointing out that Attribution is **required** by the [**CC-BY-SA Licence**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required?cb=1)

> Non-code contributions will continue to be available for use under the terms of CC-BY-SA
>
> “Reasonable attribution” is now required by end users of Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange.

Comment: Aren't comments part of the same CC-BY-SA license with attribution required?

Comment: Thanks, they are indeed although I don't think it's explicit on *comments*.

Comment: I just qualified myself to be an lawyer... my mother would be so proud ...

Comment: What if the answer is copied word by word from a comment left by another user with 0 attribution or credit?