# Why was this comment-summary answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer, moderators

I answered my question [Haskell key input memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43163487/haskell-key-input-memory-leak), but the answer was deleted.

[image]

There was one other answer, which addressed only part of the question; the other part of the question was answered in comments.  After a few days it was clear that no one was posting a full answer, and I wanted to record (and accept) the overall result.  So I posted my own summary.

So, why the deletion?  And, was there a better way for me to help resolve the question?

Comment: Your summary isn't terribly useful: all it does is make readers keep looking for the actual answer (assuming they haven't already seen the other answer depending on the sorting order). You might as well just accept the answer that's already there.

Comment: Adding to what bolt said, the first part of your answer is just a "Thanks" on the other answer. The second part just re-iterates a comment on your post. If you want to convert a comment to an answer [check this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/4099593). If you can [edit] that post and make it an answer, then do flag for undeletion. I'll be more than happy to undelete it. Usually, we don't create a new post just for a summary, you can leave the summary as a comment on the question, if the need be.

Comment: @BoltClock, I enjoyed luqui's answer, but it only addressed half the original question and was mostly off topic, so I don't really want to accept it.

Comment: I wouldn't call luqui's answer "mostly off topic". The part about type signatures isn't tangential -- the point is that suspicious-looking type signatures are useful symptoms when diagnosing a problem. That said, given that your answer also addresses your second sub-question, I don't think it is necessary to delete it. I have edited your answer to added a link to luqui's, in order to not "make readers keep looking for the actual answer", as @BoltClock puts it.

Comment: Although I generally agree with the moderators comments above, sometimes I add a summary post when I think that none of the other answers or comments fully cover the problem. ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43319089/3681880))

Comment: This is why we want 1 question per post.

Comment: I agree that the deleted answer would have been more helpful if expanded, but it does not seem to fit any of the deletion reasons listed in the [help documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).  Maybe that documentation should mention that converting comments to answers is best done with a community wiki post.

Answer (score 18):

Adding a summary of this question's comments:

1. Your summary is not self-contained. It makes the user to read the whole thread of discussion to understand what you specifically agree ([thanks BoltClock♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347930/why-was-this-comment-summary-answer-deleted#comment465696_347930)).
2. You can improve your answer to be an actual answer and flag for a moderator to undelete it ([thanks Bhargav Rao♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347930/why-was-this-comment-summary-answer-deleted#comment465701_347930))
3. You said that there is one answer that has helped with just the first part of your question and not with the second one. That's why we prefer small and simple questions and we avoid broad questions. Usually, you should ask one question per question ([thanks Braiam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347930/why-was-this-comment-summary-answer-deleted#comment465822_347930)).

---

So, I agree with this moderator action. Your answer is not a summary of comments, it's just a "thank you" + "doing X may solve the problem".

If you want to make a summary, explain the ideas and link to the comments to give the reader the option to read the original comment (like I did in this answer). Your answer **must** be self-contained. Don't force the reader to read the full thread of comments to understand the comment that you are talking about.

Instead of writing

> that explanation is correct

You could have written

> I agree with USER[link-to-comment] that doing FOO and BAR solves the problem 1, but problem 2 is not solved by this.

Just note that giving a partial answer is OK. If you write a summary-answer, make it useful at least as a partial answer. If the summary is just a set of questions, edit and improve the question instead of creating an answer.

Comment: Actually, although my summary was brief, I don't think it required anyone to read the rest of the discussion.  The original question was narrowly phrased on purpose; if someone had posted my summary as an answer to me, I would have found it helpful.  That was what I was looking for!