# No way to vote "this comment is actually an answer"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, unanswered-questions

I am quite new as a registered user in Stack Overflow, though I had used it for few years not registered.

When reviewing question, particularly those said "unanswered", I found out that mostly all of them have comments, and I would say in more than 50% of them, one comment is a valid and complete answer to the question.

I honestly do not understand the motivation explained in this  meta question

[Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat)

Why does it have to be so complicated?

Simply speaking; I would rather like to have the ability to "vote this comment as an answer". Such comments could be highlighted with special color or whatever artefact that would at first glance allow to identify them.

I base my thought on the fact that as non-registered users , I was maybe not interested by reading a flow of comments but by getting to the point.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't complicated. It is actually rather simple: **Comments cannot be answers.**

So, there is no point in allowing you to vote that a comment *could* be an answer, because a comment *can never be* an answer. **Only answers can be answers.**

If a question doesn't yet have an answer, then it hasn't been answered. If you can answer the question, then *you should answer it*! It doesn't matter whether you base that answer on information you find in the comments, information you find in the documentation, information you find on Google, or information you find scrawled on a stone tablet (although you should always credit whatever source inspired you).

> I was maybe not interested by reading a flow of comments but by getting to the point.

This is exactly why comments cannot be answers. Nobody wants to read a bunch of comments in order to find the answer.

The philosophy of Stack Exchange is a simple one: there are questions, and then there are answers. Questions need answers, and people who have questions need to be able to find those answers quickly and easily. The *best* answers should rise to the top by voting, while the not-so-good answers should sink to the bottom.

Comment: *"The best answers should rise to the top by voting"* unless a worse one is accepted.... *sigh!*

Comment: Imagine, then, if we could have accepted comments, @Paulie!

Comment: Sorry to be argumentative, but I do not understand your argumentation. Why a comment, posted by someone, can not be judged as an acceptable answer by someone else ?

I don't see why a comment could not be mutated to an answer...

Concerning your final argument : If i have a problem, and I found that someone have aske a similar problem, but there are only comments, then I have to browse through all of them. If one was tagged as "potential answer" at least, I would go for this one first. So for me being strict  create mess and slow down people consulting Stack Overflow.

Comment: @sandwood *"Why a comment, posted by someone, can not be judged as an acceptable answer by someone else"* who said that isn't possible? That can happen, in fact that would be excellent. And that person should then create the answer, right there and then.