# Should I edit my answer to handle an unanswered question?

Tags: discussion, answers

I'm going through my old posts on SO that are unanswered to try and clean up some loose ends. I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586822/filtering-reducing-df-in-pandas/42586933#42586933) and want to know how to handle unanswered questions where the answer is in the comment. [A google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=meta%20stack%20how%20to%20handle%20unanswered%20questions) turned up [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments) where the answer states:

> The better solution is to simply leave an @username reply for that person

However that talks about accepting an answer on *your* question. I also somehow found [this meta from server fault](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1886/how-to-handle-unanswered-questions-that-have-the-answer-in-a-comment-or-edited-i/1931) where it states:

> Steal comments that answer the question and post them as an answer.

The problem there is, I already posted an answer to this question. Do I edit the question and try to "steal" this? The OP last logged in on 11/6/2017 - but does not seem active. Will (s)he even accept the answer?

My goal is to clean up my old posts. What should I do in these cases where I left an answer, but the answer is in the comments

EDIT: after @tagging the person who posted the comment to leave an answer, they have put the answer in the question.

Comment: Given that you've already answered the question, why do you think the question is unanswered?  You've answered it.  Do you not think your answer is correct?  If so, why did you post it, and if you think it's not correct, why haven't you corrected it or deleted it.

Comment: `Will (s)he even accept the answer?` You have no reason to care.  Answer questions so that they'll have good answers, not because all you care about is getting it accepted.

Comment: I think the short answer is "Nothing". The OP has clearly found an answer to their question in the comments and doesn't seem to be that active. It is their responsibility to "tidy" up their own post and they have the ability to self answer their question. If the question does not have an accepted answer, who cares? It's been answered and doesn't seem particularly useful to future users anyway.

Comment: @Servy, My answer is close to the one in the comments, I was unsure of the OPs needs (i guess... it's an old post). Also.. I dont really care about the points - i just thought it'd help the community if it was marked as answered. The "heart" of this question is to simply ask what to do.

Comment: @MattR Whilst that would help the community, we can't force the OP to accept the answer. Especially if they're not online. Leave a comment @'ing them and ask them to either accept and answer or write their own answer and accept it.

Comment: @MattR If you aren't sure what the question is asking then the question is unclear and *you shouldn't be answering at all*.  You should be working with the OP to try to clarify the question.  If the question has a good answer then *that's* what's helpful to the community.  Having it marked as answered or not is entirely irrelevant to the post's usefulness.

Comment: I'm also 100% sure that this question has been asked and answered before. Might be worth flagging it as a dupe, if the dupe is accepted then it doesn't matter if the question has an accepted answer or not, because it's a duplicate.

Comment: @EthanField No, you should not be commenting to tell the OP to accept an answer.  Such comments are inappropriate, and merit deletion.  Flag any such comments you see.

Comment: @Servy *Answer questions so that they'll have good answers...*, you say that but most don't believe that.

Comment: @mega6382 I was saying that's what they should do.  I realize that lots and lost of people care way more about earning points than posting good answers.

Comment: @Servy, I feel some hostility here, this post is a from march, when I was just a SO nooby, so now- I'm trying to clean it up. If I should mark it as a dupe, I will do so. If I should try and ask for an accept, I will do so.If i should delete my answer, I will do so. I'm trying to *learn* the community here - SO has been very helpful to me and I would like to give back

Comment: @Servy I stated "Leave a comment @'ing them and ask them to either accept and answer or write their own answer and accept it." In this situation the OP has expressly stated that they have been given a solution to their answer in the comments. As such it makes sense to ask the user to either accept an answer if either of the given answers directly answer their question and are high quality, or for the OP to post their own answer with the solution that was given to them in the comments.

Comment: @MattR And I'm telling you that it's inappropriate to ask the OP to accept an answer.  You should not be posting such comments.  If you see such a comment, you should flag it so that a moderator can delete it.  Since you're trying to learn what's appropriate, I'm trying to ensure that you learn properly, and don't pick up bad habits like telling the OP to accept an answer which is not something that anyone should be doing, and so that you'll know that you should flag any such comments that you see so that they can be deleted.

Comment: @EthanField If they want to accept an answer, they can accept an answer.  If they don't want to accept an answer, that's fine too.  Pestering the OP to accept an answer is rude and not helpful, which is why such comments merit flagging (and there's even built in tools to delete such comments more easily).  If you really think that the information in the comments belongs in an answer, and that none of the existing answers are suitable, then you can post an answer yourself with that solution (citing others' work as appropriate), there's no need to tell anyone else to do it for you.

Comment: @Servy *Telling* an OP to accept a answer is inappropriate, *asking* them to accept an answer or write their own is perfectly fine and may trigger a response of "But my question isn't answered yet" which could then lead to a discussion which eventually resolves the question. Comments would need to be cleaned up afterwards but only positives can come from that.

Comment: @servy.. May i suggest a better teaching style? haha. Anyway.. check the edit. The comment was not posted as an answer - the world is now at piece and a +1 for SO in my eyes. Side note: should we be posting these comments as answers? ;)

Comment: @servy "If you really think that the information in the comments belongs in an answer, and that none of the existing answers are suitable, then you can post an answer yourself with that solution" --- what if i already posted an answer? Hence the question here on Meta

Comment: @EthanField No, going around asking people to accept answers *isn't* appropriate.  Again, such comments merit flagging for deletion.  Constantly being pestered to accept answers has caused so much frustration for people in the past that SO has had to implement numerous features to try to stop people from posting such comments, because they were so disruptive.

Comment: @MattR If you think that information doesn't need to be posted as an answer, then don't do anything, you already have already posted the answer that you think is the best.  Why would you be worried that an answer that you think is worse than the existing answers isn't posted as an answer?

Comment: @Servy I'm not talking about users saying "Me sir, pick me, my answer solved your problem". I'm talking about leaving a polite notice to say "If your question is answered, please can you mark the appropriate answer as accepted, otherwise can you explain why your question isn't answered and we can help you with this.". That to me is only a positive thing and is completely appropriate. Why do you think it's rude?

Comment: @servy... I'm not understanding you. Nor do i believe you are understanding me - I feel as if you are making assumptions behind my motives. I don't want to have a comment war here - my GOAL is for a win on SO. I'll just drop this - if someone would like to post a "this is how it should be handled answer" I will accept it.

Comment: @Servy I usually ask OP to accept a solution, any solution not mine specific though.

Comment: @EthanField Both comments have the same problem.  Sure it's only positives for *you* to ask the OP to accept an answer.  It's not all positives to have people constantly asking you to accept answers when you haven't done so.

Comment: @EthanField While I don't think it's rude, personally, the general consensus is that such comments are noise. Users are already prompted by the system to consider accepting an answer, I guess the comments are considered redundant

Comment: @mega6382 And you shouldn't do that.  And anytime you see such a comment, you should flag it.

Comment: @Clive In situations such as this though, where the user has specifically stated that their problem has been resolved in a comment rather than accepting an answer, is it not appropriate to advise them of the proper course of action? They quite clearly haven't paid attention to the system advising them of what to do, perhaps they'll listen to a real human.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What am I supposed to do with a question that got solved by comments instead of answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360366/what-am-i-supposed-to-do-with-a-question-that-got-solved-by-comments-instead-of) and [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat)