# Search for unanswered, non-"on hold", non-duplicate questions

Tags: discussion, search

It's pretty easy to search for unanswered SO questions:

```
[optional-tag-here] answers:0
```

to find questions that still need answering (which allows sorting by time - and as far as I know, that's not possible on the `unanswered` tab).

But this often comes up with questions that are unanswered because the poster got their answer in the comments (although that issue has been discussed a lot, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251597/7315159) and elsewhere), and, more annoyingly, questions marked as `on hold` or `duplicate`.

I tried, of course, this:

```
answers:0 -duplicate -"on hold"
```

as well as this (even though I don't think those actually are tags):

```
answers:0 -[duplicate] -[on hold]
```

but neither filtered out the duplicates and on-hold questions. And it might be a silly issue, but it would be nice not to have to filter through them when looking for questions to answer.

I'm hoping there is already a solution for this, but if not, would it make a good [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)?

Comment: `closed:no` should do it

Comment: Ah, and `duplicate:no` too. I didn't know about those - thanks!

Comment: [Advanced search options](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) lists all the other special operators.

Comment: *which allows sorting by time - and as far as I know, that's not possible on the unanswered tab* IIRC, we had that with the new nav they were trying out so it may come back when they change the site navigation again.

Answer (score 2):

The following works:

```
answers:0 score:-3 is:question duplicate:no closed:no
```

- The posting has *exactly* `0` **answers**.
- The posting **`is_a_question`**? yes
- The **score** of the posting is *at least* `-3` (not exactly `-3`). Posts scoring `+1` or `+2` or `+99` will also be shown.
- Question **`is_duplicate`**? `No`
- The post **`is_closed`**? `No`

If you want specific search tags, such as `python` but not `keras` you can add those tags as well:

```
[python] -[keras] answers:0 score:-3 is:question  duplicate:no closed:no
```