# How to close a question that is not necessarily bad, but is no longer relevant?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons

[Trying to import a CSV file with OpenCSV, but the information comes as null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49504676/trying-to-import-a-csv-file-with-opencsv-but-the-information-comes-as-null)

The OP has solved his problem, and there doesn't seem much benefit in keeping the question open, as the problem is relatively specific to his data model - or is there?

I don't feel like any of the reasons I can choose from to close the question do not apply - the question is well formulated, and the fact that it was difficult to answer it without knowing the table structure of OP wasn't obvious or a good reason for closure.

At this point, it seems the only good thing that can come out of leaving the question open is OP turning his comment to an answer. Other people answering would not improve the question.

How to handle questions like that?

- close it? (for what reason?)
- comment that the OPs comment should be turned into an answer and accepted? (this is what I would do with my own questions)
- leave alone? (then it looks like the question is still open when in reality, it is solved)
- Take OPs comment and write an answer? (that feels like trying to get rewarded for the OP solving his problem on his own, and not like an improvement)

Comment: At least one reason applies in my view: Off topic -> a problem that can no longer be reproduced

Comment: A downvote is the usual way to inspire an SO user to remove the post.  Getting it deleted is possible, but a heck of a lot of work.  That has to start with voting it off topic, "problem can no longer be reproduced" is a decent fit.

Comment: downvotes don't work so well with 1 rep users.

Comment: Also why would I downvote if I don't think the question is bad a-priori?

Comment: It is also useful to help other SO users from wasting their time on it.  And it will get the Roomba to clean up the question after a ~month.   A DV is not just useful to mark a question as "bad".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming OP has abandoned the question now that it's solved for him/her:

- If it has some "replay value", you could copy/paste and answer as community wiki.
- Else (unable to reproduce, no value whatsoever) vote to close (and possibly downvote if it got some unjustified upvotes so roomba can work more efficiently), and ping OP in hope he/she deletes the question before that (even simpler, cheap & worth a shot)

In that last case, a chatroom like SOCVR is useful to ask (nicely, without any obligation from them) fellow closers to help you closing the question.