# Why is the number of other answers relevant in the Very Low Quality queue?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

The Very Low Quality review queue very prominently features the number of other answers in the sidebar when reviewing. Why is this relevant to how you review the question? What's the point of this feature?

Comment: I've seen far too many cases of a VLQ flag on an answer that was superior to other answers, but those other ones not being flagged.  Typically because they are already downvoted and the flagger either doesn't have enough rep to vote or doesn't want to spend it.  Blindly deleting the answer and leaving the crappy ones doesn't help anybody, you have to look.

Comment: This is the same for other queues, for example the close votes queue shows the number of answers. It is just information that can help you when making your decision. I disagree with qualifying it as prominent though.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One line answer may have some value if there are no other answers... but on a question with 10 other answers it likely would be partial reiteration of existing answers/plagiarism. So knowing number of existing answers can help you to decide between "Edit" and "Delete" or at least make you check whole post an not just single answer.

Comment: Wouldn't that imply that sometimes we should vote to keep VLQ answers around, though?

Comment: @EJoshuaS Yes, if the answer has value, it should not be deleted. You can't decide solely on the content of an answer if it is VLQ. A one-liner or even a single word can be valuable. Other factors determine if it adds lasting value to a Q/A.

Comment: @rene Wouldn't something that's VLQ also necessarily be useless, though? So if it's useful, it's decidedly not VLQ. It might be low quality, but its usefulness would imply that it's not *very* low quality.

Comment: @EJoshuaS yes, that is for you to decide, right? If it is in the VLQ but has value then obviously you are the one that needs to rectify that mistake made by the flagger.

Answer (score 8):

A reason why I used to use the number of other answers was when judging a post as a "Thank you answer". (I guess you are referring to the LQPQ when you say "Very Low Quality Queue", as the VLQ Queue is a mod only queue). Consider an answer like this:

> Thank you Skon Jeet, your suggestion to do foo while using bar instead of fiz worked properly as expected.

This would be a blatant NAA, if and only if, there is another post. Here is where the number of other answers come to help.

If there are answers, then I'd recommend deletion with the canned "Don't post Thanks as answer, accept the other answer". If there are no other answers, then it might be a valid answer, [as they might be trying to convert a comment to an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat). In that case, I usually edit the answer into shape and attribute the answer to the commenter.