# We need to stop using Comments to Answer Questions; How should we address this?

Tags: discussion, comments

There is a very common behavior that I see from users here, both novice and veteran (especially veteran) where the comments section under a question is used as a kind of "quick answer" box, providing whatever kind of answer could be provided within 600 characters. This is bad for this site, for several reasons.

#### It makes the site harder to use

The basic mechanism by which this site works is that it functions as a Q/A site, allowing users to receive help with specific issues they are facing, and allowing visitors to benefit from the accumulated knowledge of users that have already faced the issues they are querying.

Part of ensuring this mechanism works is that both users and visitors know exactly where to look to find the answers to their questions. If users of this site are burying their answers in the comments sections of a question, then it makes use of this site more difficult.

Answers provided in comments also means that if other users attempt to do searches for their issue, potential solutions aren't going to show up in their search results. Given that this site aspires to function as a repository for valuable solutions to problems, that is incredibly self-defeating.

#### It bypasses the Reputation System

The whole point of the Reputation system is that Good Answers get upvoted, and receive higher priority on the page; Bad Answers get downvoted, and get buried, hidden, or in extreme cases, removed. Comments aren't subjected to this system of checks, which means that if bad answers are posted to the comments, we have to flag them for removal by moderators, and I don't know if you've seen the queues lately, but they've already got their work cut out for them.

Yes, it's possible for bad quality comments to get removed, but it requires Moderation. Bad quality Answers can be curated by the user base without needing to involve moderators

#### It discourages users from providing actual answers

This one is a bit of a quagmire, in that questions with a lot of comments probably had some issues with how the question was originally formulated, attracting comments discussing how the post needed to be improved, leading to a lack of answers or answers that were based on a misunderstanding of what the question was actually asking, resulting in low quality answers.

However, many questions that attract a lot of comments have done so because many of those comments are half-answers, or some form of hashing out what the correct answer might be. **This isn't what comments are for**. Comments are for working to improve a question (or answer) by asking for clarifications or suggesting different ways to word things.

When a question has a lot of half-answers (again: not subject to the Reputation system) users who might be inclined to try to provide a proper quality answer to a question instead get deterred, because the comments already contain answers.

#### It encourages "Chattiness" in the comments section

The Comments, both for answers and questions, aren't intended for free-form discussion. If a user wants to tangent off on a subject, or they want to try to hash out an answer, they should be using a Chatroom instead. [It's very easy to create a chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) when needed, and using a Chatroom to hash out an answer before providing a proper answer to the question is a far better solution than trying to handle it in the comments section.

## How should we handle this?

What is a good way to approach users who are using the comments system in this manner? I've been trying to flag comments that incorrectly attempt to answer questions, but would it be appropriate to *gently* remind users that the comments system shouldn't be used that way, or should we refrain from direct confrontation?

---

## Regarding the Duplicates

This post has since been tagged as a duplicate of a very large number of other posts dealing with similar questions about comments being used to answer questions. None of these posts satisfy my issue, for several reasons.

For starters, some of those discussions are almost half a decade old, and by this point, they reflect a stage in this stack's development that it isn't in anymore. Marking a question as a duplicate of a question 5 years older is appropriate when nothing has changed since that original question, but that isn't the case here: the site has evolved since then, and the issues the site faces are different today than they were back in 2014. I think it's valuable to reference those questions to give context for this discussion, but calling this a "duplicate" is a misuse of the convention.

Secondly, as has been made abundantly clear in the comments below this post, a lot of the answers being provided in those posts don't actually address my core issue. @Robert, for example, [advises in their 2014 answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/5241642) that Answers-as-Comments should have a Community Wiki answer created in their stead; that's not a bad response, but it doesn't address whether the original comments should be dealt with or not, and leaves open the implication that it's still okay for users to attempt to leave answers in the comments of a question, something that is [expressly prohibited by the rules of this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) (emphasis mine):

> **Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.** They can be up-voted (but not down-voted) and flagged, but do not generate reputation. There's no revision history, and when they are deleted they're gone for good.
>
> [...]
>
> #### When shouldn't I comment?
>
> Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
>
> [...]
>
> - **Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer**; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one);

Which is especially pertinent because this post managed to attract two moderators who both are openly encouraging users to leave Comments-As-Answers. The idea that moderators of this stack would openly encourage users to break the rules is... pretty incredible, if you'll forgive my understatement.

So in so many words, I don't believe this question constitutes a duplicate of the posts above.

Comment: Don't confuse answers with thinly veiled requests for clarification that look like answers.  (:

Comment: I use comments to post answers all the time, for much the same reasons as you've described in your post: answers are subject to scrutiny (sometimes I don't feel like posting an Academy-award winning answer), you can't post bare links in answers (links are sometimes definitive), the question is marginal or closed, etc.  And yes, I am aware of the irony of answering your post in the comments.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Note that neither of the answers from *Diamond Mods* (holy crap guys, really?) on this question (one is a comment on the answer below) are actual answers, so we can't downvote them, edit them, functionally comment on them, etc. That kind of proves the point of this question, doesn't it?

Comment: @GreySage: It certainly does if you believe the only relevant or useful information that exists on a site like this is in the answers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's a deflection from the issue, though. If information is useful or relevant on this site, it should be subject to the proper *scrutiny* that this site is expressly designed to facilitate. Information that shows up in the comments is difficult to find, and if it's wrong (which happens a lot even with highly voted comments!), our only recourse is to flag it for moderators: that cannot *possibly* be how this site is meant to be run—and I know this because [the Comments Help Page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) expressly says not to use comments like this.

Comment: @Xirema: If I have an authoritative link that answers someone's question, and I don't have time to compose a proper answer, my viable choices are: 1.  Post the link as a comment, 2.  Do nothing.  Certainly, if I have the time and headspace to compose an answer that meets the community's exacting standards, I will do so.

Comment: @RobertHarvey 1 is not better than 2 if the link dies a few months later. It just makes the site more frustrating to use when valuable information has disappeared due to link rot, and seeing a comment-link that purports to provide an answer to the question will make other users less likely to put in the effort of actually writing a thoughtful answer.

Comment: They have this thing called the Wayback Machine.  Seriously, is your position "if you can't help the 'right way,' don't help at all?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey Which itself has limitations, often doesn't capture the complete picture of a website, and is useless for sites that have significant amounts of multimedia components.

Comment: @Xirema: I think you have some notion of perfection that is unattainable.  Sometimes askers just need a push in the right direction.  Your community's strict requirements make that push impossible in an answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, my position is "if you're not going to put in good effort, don't put in the effort". That's consistent with the *actual rules set by this site*, and my experience in other communities has taught me that bad answers can cause more harm than no answers. A house built out of rotting wood is more likely to kill someone than an open lot.

Comment: A point for your "It makes the site harder to use" section: I think answers-as-comments make solutions less searchable. Unless I am mistaken, the stack's search does **not** include the contents of comments in its search results. If it were posted as a 'real' answer, it would. Possibly also worth quoting the Comments Help Page: "**What are comments?** Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer,"- if the stack is meant to be a useful public repository of Q&A, supporting posting answers in a format it itself describes as temporary seems counterproductive.

Answer (score 1):

If comments are getting too chatty and aren't adding any actual value to the question, you can flag for moderator assistance and that can be cleaned up.

Other than that, the best thing we can do is poke and prod and politely indicate that one *should* answer questions through the answer submission form.

Not much else we can do to *force* others to do this, but the best thing we could do is at least start showing the example.  If a user really *doesn't* want to answer the question, but their comment actually does hold value, we could answer on their behalf with a Community Wiki answer instead, which would be their comment verbatim.  Flagging *those* kinds of comments wouldn't be appropriate.

Comment: Flagging chatty comments that no longer serve a purpose is fine. Flagging comments with "this should be an answer" is *not* fine. I've declined several of those today. I absolutely refuse to destroy value by removing on-topic comments just because you think they should have been an answer. Post your own answer if you're that bothered by it.

Comment: @CodyGray:  I seem to be leaning a bit too much on context.  Your comment was exactly what I wanted to convey.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: Or I have a bit too much context that wasn't visible from the question; either way. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray: "*I absolutely refuse to destroy value by removing on-topic comments just because you think they should have been an answer.*" Have you considered using your moderation abilities to talk to the user in question, and perhaps sanction them if they repeatedly do so after talking with them? Do you even consider the posting of answers as comments to be a misuse of the site, or do you think it's fine?

Comment: No, I do not consider it a "misuse" of the site. Comments are not strictly regulated. If you're following the Code of Conduct, and you are keeping on topic, then it's a valid comment. Is it *ideal*? Not necessarily, for some of the reasons pointed out in the question. But not even close to being a reason to sanction a user. @Nicol

Comment: @CodyGray The help text seems to disagree: "When shouldn't I comment?
Comments are not recommended for any of the following: [..]

Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one);"

Comment: @Rubik The help text is fine. Comments are not *recommended* for answering. Big difference between "not recommended" and "moderators should destroy value by deleting them".

Comment: @CodyGray there also seems to be a big difference between "not recommended" and "ignore this completely" though right? You seem to be advocating for the latter.

Comment: Nowhere have I advocated for the latter, @Rubik. Where are you seeing that? My argument has been very consistent: although answering in comments is not recommended for all the reasons described in the question, *do not flag* comments that nevertheless do this, because moderators have no interest in destroying potentially valuable information because of some slavish adherence to rules/guidelines. Furthermore, in response to Nicol Bolas, I confirmed that answering in comments, while still not encouraged or advised, is not sanctionable behavior (unlike e.g. vote fraud).

Comment: @CodyGray fair point, you never say you are advocating for this. But let me ask: what is the difference between an action that is not advised but is actively participated in by all parties with no reprimand or recourse (including mods see Robert above) and something that is fine and allowable? Isn't a mod especially answering in a comment at least implicit affirmation that it is a fine and welcome thing to do? I'm just confused how you can admit that something is "not recommended" (bad and harmful) but then say that there is nothing that can be done about it.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm a little confused by the reference to "sanctionable behavior". I don't think I have indicated that I want some kind of punishment for people who break this rule; clearly, a lot of people break it, and it would be unfair to suddenly be like "enjoy this red mark on your profile for doing something that was actively encouraged by mods for years!" But removing comments and saying "this isn't how comments are meant to be used; if you want to answer the question post an actual answer" isn't going to hurt anyone.

Comment: So I'm gonna ask this politely - can y'all take this into a chat room?  Not keen on having my inbox pinged every now and then with a conversation I'm not totally vested in. :)

Comment: @Makoto Something you wouldn't be putting up with if the Mods had used an Answer for their response like they are supposed to, instead of using comments. ;)

Comment: My comment was not an answer. It was a *clarification* on Makoto's answer. I don't know why this has turned into such controversy, or how what I've said has been so badly misinterpreted. I can't be any more clear than I already have, so i don't see what it would accomplish to discuss it any further.

Comment: @CodyGray Perhaps yours was not. But Robert's above was, and between the two of you this thread definitely appears as though you are advocating that answer in comments is fine. Perhaps if one of you mods were to post an actual answer with your official stance on it then there could be a better discussion on that policy.

Comment: @CodyGray - The [meta faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) disagrees - "Comments are second class citizens on the Stack Exchange network, not designed to hold information for all eternity. They may get cleaned up at any time.*Generally, truly important information should be incorporated into an answer anyway*(either by posting a new answer, if the information answers the question at least partially, or by editing an existing answer, if the information is a minor complement or clarification of that answer)"