# Recommended way to get comment reposted as an answer

Tags: discussion

Sometimes, when I ask a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56022711/how-does-angular-handle-assignment-of-objects-when-forcibly-converting-to-boolea?noredirect=1#comment98690720_56022711), there's a comment that's really spot on and answering it. In such cases, I let a day or so go by. Then, I ask the commenting user to repost/summarize into an answer.

On occasion, they don't and I'm always unsure what to do. I understand they might be busy or simply don't regard their contribution as heavy enough. Or a gazillion other reasons.

It seems tacky and ungrateful to post an answer myself. Besides, it's not possible to upvote it then anyway.

Is there a general procedure to follow in such cases or does it depend on the particular circumstances?

Comment: Consider if https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat is the duplicate... or at very least [edit] post explaining why it is not.

Answer (score 10):

> It seems tacky and ungrateful to post an answer myself. Besides, it's not possible to upvote it then anyway.

You might pick up the information from the comment and post it as an answer yourself if you believe it's worth it.

You can leave a reference to that comment in your answer. Also you may consider to make your answer *community wiki*.

> Is there a general procedure to follow in such cases or does it depend on the particular circumstances?

No, there's no *general procedure*.
If you think your question would be helpful for future research, you may follow what I've advised above.
In other cases it might be better to simply delete your question.