# Is it okay to 'delete' a post if the post got answered in a comment?

Tags: discussion

I always wondered this. Let's say, user X posts a well-formed (basically an on-topic and good) question, which got answered with a comment which was acceptable (to the point where had it been an answer, X would have accepted it). Now, X hasn't got any *votes* on the question, nor other comments. Is it okay if X 'deletes' the post?

In my case, I usually request the person who's posted the comment to post it as an answer, which at times goes ignored (and I too delete the comment after around 48 hours). Is that fine?

Comment: You mean the OP has confirmed that the comment has solved the problem?

Comment: @akuzminykh, yes

Comment: Then it depends on you. The "nice" way is to do what you've suggested: Inform the commenter about it. The "bad" way is to just write the answer yourself. I've written so many comments that answer whole questions and then just someone comes by, copy-pastes from the comment section and just posts the answer .. I think, it's a whatever. If that's "okay" or not, depends on you. The important thing here is about "deletion": If the question provides something good/new for SO, then definitely get it answered, by the commenter or you. If it's e.g. a duplicate, then get it deleted/closed.

Comment: Here for more: [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251597/12323248)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "nice" way is to do what you've suggested: Inform the commenter about it. The "bad" way is to just write the answer yourself. I've written so many comments that answer whole questions and then someone just comes by, copy-pastes from the comment-section and just posts the answer.. I think, it's a whatever. If that's "okay" or not, depends on you. The important thing here is about "deletion": If the question provides something good/new to SO, then definitely get it answered, by the commenter or you. If it's e.g. a duplicate, then get it deleted/closed.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 I think that's more or less a subset of [meta-tag:discussion].